# Whats the use of Nullable.GetUnderlyingType, if typeof(int?) is an Int32?

Tags: c#, nullable

why is `typeof int?` an `Int32`

```
int? x = 1;
Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name);
```

If it is okay then what's the use of `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`?

Comment: I think the question is why does the code write out "Int32" instead of "Nullable<Int32>"

Comment: I think what he means is this: If calling `x.GetType().Name` can get you `Int32` in above example, why do we need Nullable.GetUnderlyingType() to find out that its `Int32`.

Comment: The assumption is false - `typeof(int?)` is `System.Nullable<Int32>`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Calling `GetType()` boxes your variable. The CLR has a special rule that `Nullable<T>` gets boxed to `T`. So `x.GetType` will return `Int32` instead of `Nullable<Int32>`.

```
int? x = 1;
x.GetType() //Int32
typeof(int?) //Nullable<Int32>
```

Since a `Nullable` containing `null` will be boxed to `null` the following will throw an exception:

```
int? x = null;
x.GetType() //throws NullReferenceException
```

To quote [MSDN on Boxing Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597(v=VS.100).aspx):

> Objects based on nullable types are only boxed if the object is non-null. If `HasValue` is `false`, the object reference is assigned to `null` instead of boxing
>
> If the object is non-null -- if `HasValue` is `true` -- then boxing occurs, but only the underlying type that the nullable object is based on is boxed. Boxing a non-null nullable value type boxes the value type itself, not the `System.Nullable<T>` that wraps the value type.

Comment: @PeterLillevold I think that's done (maybe after your comment though) but in any case, SO is a collaborative environment - you are more than welcome to edit an answer (or question) yourself and format it.

Comment: @OferZelig yes, I'm well aware of that. I think back in 2010 I just wanted to give CodesInChaos the chance to do it :)

Answer (score 11):

This example is a bit confused, because:

```
int? x = 1;
```

creates a `Nullable<int>` like you expect; however:

```
Type type = x.GetType();
```

is a call to a non-virtual method on `object`, which isn't (and can't be) overridden - therefore this is a **boxing** operation; and `Nullable<T>` has special boxing rules:

- if it is empty, it boxes to `null`
- if it has a value, the *value* is boxed and returned

i.e.

```
int? x = 1;
int y = 1;
```

box to **exactly** the same thing.

Therefore, you are passing `typeof(int)` to `GetUnderlyingType`.

A more illustrative example of when this helps is when using reflection:

```
class Foo {
    public int? Bar {get;set;}
}
...
Type type = typeof(Foo); // usually indirectly
foreach(var prop in type.GetProperties()) {
     Type propType = prop.PropertyType,
          nullType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propType);

     if(nullType != null) {
         // special code for handling Nullable<T> properties;
         // note nullType now holds the T
     } else {
         // code for handling other properties
     }
}
```

Comment: `GetUnderlingType` - my favorite typo of the day. Also, `tupe`.

Comment: @Marc: Actually, `GetType` is **not** `virtual` and that's why it requires boxing (it calls the implementation of `Object.GetType` and that requires the receiver to be of type `Object`). If it were virtual, and was overridden in the derived class, it wouldn't require boxing.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I was unclear in my terminology; it *is* a virtcall, but it is to a non-virtual method that resolves to object hence needs boxing. As would a virtcall to a virtual method that hasn't been overridden. I know you know that - I'm just adding full context ;p

Comment: you mean that x.GetType() and x.Value.GetType() are the same? strange isnt it. and when you do reflection on some method returning nullable type, you get something like Nullable'1

Comment: @Mubashir if you think *that's* strange, it has another consequence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/194671#194671

Comment: @Mobashir: There's a slight difference between the two if the object is `null`. In the former, the object will be boxed and the method will be called on the resulting `null` reference, which causes the *runtime* to throw `NullReferenceException`, while in the latter, the `Value` property (which doesn't require boxing) will check and throws `InvalidOperationException` if the value is indeed null.

Comment: One more thing, Nullable<T> is a struct but allows null assignment. Nullable<int> x = null;

Comment: @Mubashir well, not quite - it *pretends* to - but that is actually the C# compiler changing the code for you (into something that isn't *really* null). It does this for most operations involving `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Afaik the boxing of `Nullable<T>` to `T` is a feature of the runtime and not the C# compiler.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - do you mean to object? `T?` to `T` isn't boxing.

Comment: I mean that if I box a `Nullable<T>` by casting to `(object)` it is a boxed `T` afterwards and not a boxed `T?`. And that the decision that is should become a boxed `T` and not a boxed `T?` is made by the runtime, and not because the C# compiler creates some extra code.

Comment: Mark is correct all methods against a generic method are called as `constrained !!T`, `callvirt Method` the reasoning is that they have to normalize the calling convention between struct and class types. However, in this case the normalization which normally prevents boxing cannot as `GetType` only exists on object as it is a non-virt method. When dealing in generic methods all conversion to object and interfaces are all spaced with a `box !!T` instruction too, which just gets compiled away into a `nop` for ref types.

Answer (score 4):

Its for when you don't know its `Int32`.

### Example:

```
    public Type GetNullableUnderlyingType<T>(Nullable<T> obj) 
        where T : struct
    {
        return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(Nullable<T>));
    }
```

Here, you can pass any `Nullable` object and get it to return it's underlying type.

Comment: The problem here is; to call that method in regular code, the generics must be resolved at the caller. Which means that the caller **already knows the type**. And (to match the signature) they must **already know** it is nullable etc. If they already know... why are they asking?

Answer (score 2):

When you write `int?` it's as if you've written `Nullable<int>`. That's the type you're looking for, I think.

Comment: exactly, should it not be something like Nullable'1 like i have for List<int> as List'1

Answer (score 1):

Mainly its for dealing with a generic method::
e.g.

```
public static void SomeMethod<T>(T argument)
{
     if(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T) != null)
     {
             /* special case for nullable code go here */
     }
     else
     {
            /* Do something else T isn't nullable */
     }
}
```

It's important to know this, as certain things that are very cheap can be wildly expensive on nullable's. For instance, `if(argument == null)` is normally super cheap, but when done in a generic method on a `Nullable<T>` is forced to box the `argument` to get a null reference. Your best bet is to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` which will slow everything else down, but makes nullable's not suffer.