# How to invoke Nullable.GetUnderlyingType on an object? What is the difference between Nullable.GetUnderlyingtype and .GetType

Tags: .net, nullable

I want to understand usage of Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(). When should it be used?

Also, in the following example, How can we make use of GetUnderlyingType instead of GetType

```
    int? x = 1;
    Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name);
```

I tried to follow [Whats the use of Nullable.GetUnderlyingType, if typeof(int?) is an Int32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518097/whats-the-use-of-nullable-getunderlyingtype-if-typeofint-is-int32) link, but kept my head scratching.

Comment: You don't need it, since you know the type of x statically...

Comment: My question is for the case where we dont know the type at compile time.
x.GetType can throw exception if x is null.

Comment: When should it be used? When you need to know the underlying type of a nullable! It's also handy to test whether or not *any* arbitrary type is a nullable: `if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToTest) != null) { /* typeToTest is nullable */ }`

Comment: Well after little thought, I understood, it is not possible to have type not known statically, and getting null value. So my comment is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have obtained a property of a class via reflection (call it vProp), the following should work:

```
Type tNullType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(vProp.PropertyType);
Type tType = tNullType ?? vProp.PropertyType;
```

tType will return the actual property type, whether Nullable or not, that you can use for casting or other similar operations.