# why does n.GetHashCode() work but n.GetType() throws and exception?

Tags: c#, exception

I am teaching myself C# (I don't know much yet). In this simple example:

```
bool?          n = null;

Console.WriteLine("n               = {0}", n);
Console.WriteLine("n.ToString()    = {0}", n.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("n.GetHashCode() = {0}", n.GetHashCode());

// this next statement causes a run time exception

Console.WriteLine("n.GetType()     = {0}", n.GetType());
```

Intuitively I understand why the GetType() method would throw an exception.  The instance n is null which would explain that but, why don't I get an exception for the same reason when using n.GetHashCode() and ToString() ?

Thank you for your help,

John.

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/194671#194671

Comment: mookid, great thread.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`GetHashCode()` is a virtual method overridden in `Nullable<T>`: when it's called on a `Nullable<T>` value, the `Nullable<T>` implementation is used, without any boxing.

`GetType()` *isn't* a virtual method, which means that when it's called, the value is boxed first... and boxing a "null" nullable value results in a null reference - hence the exception. We can see this from the IL:

```
static void Main()
{
    bool? x = null;
    Type t = x.GetType();
}
```

is compiled to:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool> nullable,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Type 'type')
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldloca.s nullable
    L_0003: initobj [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
    L_0009: ldloc.0 
    L_000a: box [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
    L_000f: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Type [mscorlib]System.Object::GetType()
    L_0014: stloc.1 
    L_0015: ret 
}
```

The important bit here is L_000a: the `box` instruction before the `callvirt` instruction at L_000f.

Now compare that with the equivalent code calling `GetHashCode`:

```
static void Main()
{
    bool? x = null;
    int hash = x.GetHashCode();
}
```

compiles to:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool> nullable,
        [1] int32 num)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldloca.s nullable
    L_0003: initobj [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
    L_0009: ldloca.s nullable
    L_000b: constrained [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<bool>
    L_0011: callvirt instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Object::GetHashCode()
    L_0016: stloc.1 
    L_0017: ret 
}
```

This time we have a `constrained` instruction/prefix before `callvirt`, which essentially means "You don't need to box when you call the virtual method." From the [`OpCodes.Constrained`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx) documentation:

> The constrained prefix is designed to allow callvirt instructions to be made in a uniform way independent of whether thisType is a value type or a reference type.

(Follow the link for more information.)

Note that the way boxing of nullable value types work also means that even for a *non-null* value, you won't get `Nullable<T>`. For example consider:

```
int? x = 10;
Type t = x.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(t == typeof(int?)); // Prints False
Console.WriteLine(t == typeof(int)); // Prints True
```

So the type you get out is the *non-nullable* type involved. A call to `object.GetType()` will *never* return a `Nullable<T>` type.

Comment: Jon!! thank you very much.  I started studying C# using your book "C# in Depth" but, it quickly got over my head.  As a result, I went to the "C# Programming Guide" of VS2008.
Your explanation makes perfect sense.  Thank you again,

John

Comment: @Tomas: Becoming longer over time, I'm afraid - but I like going into detail :)

Comment: @Hex440bx: Sounds like a wise step - C# in Depth really does assume you already know a certain amount of C#. Hopefully it'll become useful to you over time. In this case, read chapter 4 carefully - I mention the boxing behaviour there, although I can't remember whether or not I call out this particular case.

Comment: There is no doubt in my mind your book will be very useful in the future.  It has already been useful in the sense that the first two chapters gave me a good idea of the features in C# that I do _not_ want to miss.  :-)

Comment: @Jon: So I see :). Great with the details explaining your first shorter answer which I think nailed the question. And who doesn't like to see compiled code :)