# Why does Nullable<> not hide GetType?

Tags: c#, .net

Coming from this question [why does n.GetHashCode() work but n.GetType() throws and exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547808/why-does-n-gethashcode-work-but-n-gettype-throws-and-exception) the answer Jon gave led me to this question: Why isn't `Nullable<>` hiding `GetType`:

```
public new Type GetType()
{
    return GetValueOrDefault().GetType();
}
```

Because then this

```
int? i = null;
Console.WriteLine(i.GetType().Name);
```

should work, shouldn't it? Am I missing something obvious? What are the caveats? I tried google but didn't find any satisfactory explanation.

**Update**: To clarify: a bit. This works:

```
int? i = null;
Console.WriteLine(i.GetHashCode());
```

The only reason why `i.GetType()` throws is because `GetType` is not virtual and could not be overridden. So when calling it `i` gets boxed into object which result in `null` and then it throws. However if `Nullable` would be implemented like this

```
 public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
 {
     ....
     public new Type GetType()
     {
         return GetValueOrDefault().GetType();
     }
 }
```

Then it would make the behaviour more consistent (imho) in the regards that all of this would work instead of just the first two calls:

```
 int? i = null;
 Console.WriteLine(i.GetHashCode());
 Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
 Console.WriteLine(i.GetType());
```

Comment: How would you hide a method that inherits from `Object`?

Comment: Furthermore, why would you want to?

Comment: yeah, indeed, why would 'null.GetType()' throw null reference exception :)

Comment: `int?` is syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>` which is a value type. The only reason you can assign `null` to it is because there is special behaviour implemented in the CLR. So `i.GetType()` is technically **not** the same as `null.GetType()`. It ends up resulting in it due to the reason described above and in the question I linked to althoug I think it could have been avoided - but it wasn't. Therefor my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because `GetType` returns the exact *runtime* type of the current instance. In this case it has no runtime type because it references `null`.

Consider this example:

```
  MyBaseClass myBase = null;
  MyDerivedClass myDerived = null;
  object o = myDerived;
  MyBaseClass b = myDerived;
```

If `myBase.GetType()` would return `MyBaseClass` and `myDerived.GetType()` would return `MyDerivedClass`, then what should `o.GetType()` and `b.GetType()` return?

The reason `Nullable` doesn't simply hide `object.GetType` and return its compile time type when it is `null`, is probably because it would break `GetType`'s contract.

Comment: As explained above `int?` is the same as `Nullable<int>` and when you call `GetType` on a `Nullable<T>` it will return `typeof(T)`. That's the existing behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisWue No it doesn't return typeof(T), it calls `GetType` inherited from `object` and returns its runtime type. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx. Maybe you're confused with `Type.GetType`?

Comment: Ok, maybe I expressed it not quite right but `GetType` returns the underlying type when called on `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: This answer is not good. It says _it has no runtime type because it references `null`._ but that is incorrect. It's a value type, there is an object with a runtime type. Also, to convince yourself that the current behavior cunfuses many, see the number of questions linked to the thread [Nullable type is not a nullable type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785358/). The call kind-of gives the wrong answer today, but there's no real need to make this `GetType()` call for a value type. See my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why they didn't do that is that it is generally a bad idea to hide an inherited method with a `new` method with the same name and signature.

*If* they chose to actually hide `Object.GetType()`, the question is if they should return the type of the `Nullable<T>` struct, or the underlying type. This would be either:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    ....
    public new Type GetType()
    {
        return typeof(Nullable<T>);
    }
}
```

or:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    ....
    public new Type GetType()
    {
        return typeof(T);
    }
}
```

If you have:

```
int? i = null;
```

or:

```
int? i = 42;
```

the "real" runtime type of `i` is certainly `Nullable<int>` (also known as `int?`). Of course, introducing a new `GetType` method now (in .NET version 5.0, say) which returned `Nullable<int>` would be a breaking change. That's because the way it is today, the `i` will be boxed into either a `null` reference or a boxed `int` (***not*** a boxed `Nullable<int>`) because of the magical boxing of `Nullable<>`.

**But:** There is really no reason for a (capable) programmer to ever use `.GetType()` on a variable (or other expression) of ***compile-time type*** `T?`, because he *knows* the actual type is the same as the compile-time type, namely `typeof(T?)`. He also knows that the underlying type is `typeof(T)`.

For the same reason, for a "usual" (not nullable) value type `T`, it is not useful for a programmer to use `.GetType()` when the compile-time type is `T`, because he *knows* the result will always be `typeof(T)`. This is because all value types are *sealed* types. Also, for a for a reference type which is sealed (and for which no type parameter is co- or contravariant), `.GetType()` is useless.

To give an example:

```
string str = ...;
...
var t = str.GetType(); // This is really useless. If str is null
                       // an exception is thrown. Otherwise the
                       // t will ALWAYS be typeof(string) because
                       // the class System.String is a sealed class.
```

---

The base classes of the `Nullable<>` struct are `System.ValueType` and `System.Object`, and `Nullable<>` implements no interfaces. But if our `i` from before is cast and put into a variable of compile-time type `ValueType` or `object` (or `dynamic`), it *loses* its identity of `Nullable<int>` and becomes an ordinary boxed value type. Therefore, even if `Object.GetType()` were made `virtual` (which would of course be extremely dangerous) it wouldn't even be helpful.

Conclusion: The runtime type is `Nullable<>` if and only if the compile-time type is `Nullable<>`, so this "problem" is not interesting to fix.