# Why does a `null` Nullable<T> have a hash code?

Tags: c#, nullable

Bit of a weird question...

But can anyone give me a justification for why this would be expected behaviour?

This just seems totally odd to me....

```
//Makes perfect sense
object o = null;
o.GetHashCode().Dump();
```

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

```
//Seems very odd
int? i = null;
i.GetHashCode().Dump();
```

> 0

This obviously means:

```
int? zero = 0;
int? argh = null;

zero.GetHashCode() == argh.GetHashCode(); //true
```

Comment: Good question. However be aware that only because two hashcodes are equal doesn´t mean the two *instances* are equal also.

Comment: Interestingly boxing the nullable int to `object` and calling `GetHashCode` again yields to an NRE.

Comment: This question is over my head so apologies for my ignorance, but for my benefit the documentation says of `Nullable<T>.GetHashCode`: `The hash code of the object returned by the Value property if the HasValue property is true, or zero if the HasValue property is false.`. Since `HasValue` here is `false`, I'd expect 0. Isn't this the answer?

Comment: If you mean "why does it not throw", then your question's [a duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5547808/4137916). Well, related, really, not exactly a duplicate. I suppose it *could* have an explicit `throw new NullReferenceException` in there, as confusing as that would be.

Comment: int? is a struct, syntax sugar for `Nullable<int>`.  A struct always has a hash code and never produces NRE.

Comment: Follow up question for you to consider: what does `GetType` do when its receiver is a null `int?` vs what does it do when its receiver is a non-null `int` -- can you predict what the program will do before you run it?  Now try it; was your prediction correct? Are you surprised?

Comment: There are `2^32` possible hash codes, and `2^32 + 1` possible nullable ints, so *at least* two `int?`s have to have the same hash code. It ought not to be that big a surprise that the pair with equal hash codes are 0 and null.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The point here is that

```
int? i = null;
```

does not create a variable `i` which is `null`, but (by performing an implicit cast) a `Nullable<int>` instance which does not have a value.
This means the object/instance is not `null` (and as `Nullable<T>` is a struct/value type it actually can't be `null`) and therefore has to return a hash-code.

This is also documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.1):

> The hash code of the object returned by the Value property if the HasValue property is true, or zero if the HasValue property is false.

Comment: You might want to explain that it's because `Nullable` is a value type...

Comment: Ok - thanks for linking to the docs. I imagine some language designers argued about this for 2 weeks before agreeing the implementation - Really, GetHashCode should return Nullable<Int>() somehow :)

Comment: Object cant be null, but if you ask if it is null `i == null` it will return true :-)

Answer (score 16):

`int?` is actually just shorthand for `Nullable<int>`, a struct which wraps the `int` type in order to allow it to be null. Nullable can be used with any value type.

Because Nullable is actually a struct (it can't be null), it has to return *something* for a hash code, and normally it would return the value's hash code (presumably in order to be as transparent as possible to the value within). When the value is null, [it is hard-coded in the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs#L70-L72) to return 0 by default:

```csharp
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return hasValue ? value.GetHashCode() : 0;
}
```

Comment: It could throw the same NullReferenceException, instead - which IMO would be more correct,

Comment: If it threw a NullReferenceException and you had a `HashSet<int?>`. You can't add a null value to it. You would get a NullReferenceExeption. This isn't really expected behaviour - why would you use a HashSet<int?> if it can't accept a null value? You would simply use HashSet<int>. [Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jfhu8G). It makes more sense in the general framework if it doesn't throw an exception and better fits the idea of using Nullable, IMHO.

Comment: @john, what happens when you add `null` to a `HashSet<string>`?

Comment: So, whether it throws a NullReferenceException or not is inconsequential, or else it would fail on the null string case.

Comment: @Arturo I concede. You're right. The [HashSet](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs#L1712-L1719) code also has the same "if null, hashcode is 0" logic within it, and a null nullable would obviously evaluate to true there. So, even if GetHashCode threw a NullReferenceException, it would still work as expected.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like documented behaviour of `Nullable<T>.GetHashCode()`, [as documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axk9ks7d(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The hash code of the object returned by the Value property if the
>   HasValue property is true, or zero if the HasValue property is false.