# C# paradoxical and controversial constructs

Tags: c#, .net

The purpose of this post is to collect all neat and tricky c# constructs and issues that don't occur on everyday basis.

So here goes:

**Issue 1** (this one I've discovered by my own)

What will be printed on screen?

```
class Program
{
    private static String Function(out String str)
    {
        str = "Hello ";
        return "world!";
    }
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String x = Function(out x);

        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts? :)

**Issue 2** Creating generic collection (such as List<> or Dictionary<>) of anonymous types, is it possible?

```
  var Customer = new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
  var customerList = new List<????>();
```

Consider this one found [here](http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-create-generic-list-of-anonymous.html):

```
static List<T> CreateList<T>(params T[] values)
{
    return new List<T>(values);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new { A = "Hello", B = "world!" };

    var list = CreateList(x);

    list.Add(new { A = "Hello again", B = "world!" });
}
```

Share your findings. Thank you!

Comment: I'm kind of curious what you were doing when you discovered what happens when you assign a return value to an out parameter...

Comment: Since this question has no "answer", I'd recommend marking it as a community wiki if you don't want it to be closed.

Comment: I don't assign return value to an out parameter, the return value is different from the one that is assigned to an out parameter

Comment: I don't want it to be closed, I want to collect interesting aspects of the C# language

Comment: @Lu4 - Well then in the words of Michael Ironside: _you know what to do!_

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the strangest corner case you've seen in C# or .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net)

Comment: Richard, I'm not Rico, I don't know...

Comment: @Richard: what is it he knows how to do? CW questions no longer exist.

Comment: Ok, this is duplicate, what to do next?

Comment: @John - Oh really? In that case, @Lu4 just see how it pans out.

Comment: Man, I kind of agree with this question being closed; but at the same time I kind of feel like SO isn't as much fun as it used to be :(

Comment: I don't agree to the fact that people are deciding that this question is not constructive, it depends to whom it is constructive and to whom it is not, if I spent time asking it then it is somewhat valuable to me. Hearing this things is like a spit in the face... :(

Comment: @Lu4: The community is bigger than the individual here — much to the detriment of a lot of us :(

Comment: Quite similar, and not (yet) closed because of its age: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1246336/60761

Answer (score 2):

For your first example, the value of `x` will be the return value of the method, since method invocation (including out arguments) happens before the return value is assigned.

As far as the list goes, you should be able to do this:

```
var list = new[]
{
    new { a = 1, b = "hi" },
    new { a = 1, b = "hi" }
}.ToList();
```

Though I'm not sure if the compiler will determine both anonymous types to be equal.

Comment: yes it will, otherwise you would end up having list of different types :)

Comment: What I mean is, it may not compile.

Comment: Type unification would (at least in this case) ensure that the code compiles.