# Declared variable used in initializer expression - meaning?

Tags: c++, variables, declaration, definition, boost-spirit

Taken from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814209/parsing-text-to-make-a-tree-data-structure/7815152#7815152):

```
static const qi::rule<std::string::iterator, ast_t()> node = 
'{' >> *node >> '}' | +~qi::char_("{}");
```

Note that a constant var of name `node` is declared, but `node` is used to initialize this constant.

What's going on here?

Helpful "Similar Questions" shows [that it is valid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898149/is-type-name-name-ever-valid-code-in-c) in general, but what does it do in this spirit expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a recursive definition, very similar to [this example with linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898149/is-type-name-name-ever-valid-code-in-c/6898501#6898501). A grammar rule is constructed which refers back to itself. It works because `operator*` takes its argument by (`const`) reference.