# LINQ-to-SQL DataContext is null on certain server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very unusual problem. I have an ASP.NET application that uses LINQ-to-SQL a lot, and works fine on most servers. However the application exists on another server on the same network, and after a recent update, whenever I open a new DataContext like this:

```
LINQDataContext dc = new LINQDataContext();
```

The dc object is null, so I get object reference errors trying to use it. I cannot replicate this on my development machine, or on the other server which the application exists on, so I'm baffled about why this could be. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `dc` a *field* (class variable) or *local* (method variable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using default constructor of your DataContext, then connection string is read from web.config. So we could make a suggestion that application on that server has different config without proper connection string. But there is one more thing that we've faced once in our project. In a new version of ASP location of connection string storage in config file has changed. I don't have code at my fingertips, but you could test my suggestion by using [constructor that takes connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350721.aspx) as a parameter. Read connection string from config manually or just hardcode it for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can't happen. When you call the `new` operator on a standard .Net type, there are two possible outcomes:

1. the constructor returns normally and the value is assigned
2. the constructor throws an exception, the value is not assigned

Unless you `catch` the exception right away, and ignore it, you can be sure that the variable has been assigned. This means your problem probably lies somewhere else.

(Technically, there is a third option – the constructor never returns and loops infinitely, but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: Actually *in a deliberately crafted* edge case you can make "new" return null for a class, but you can't do it for a data-context. Only mentioned for the insanity of it (it doesn't apply to this question). Ill dig out the example if you want ;) edit: it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/