# Specifying an Assembly to Create an Object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll, .net-assembly

I have a C# application. It has a referenced class library `Generic.dll`.
I have a `Document` class inside `Generic.dll`.

```
namespace Generic
{
    public class Document
    {
        public virtual string ObjectName()
        {
            return "Generic";
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created another class library `Custom.dll` and created a `Document` by inheriting the `Document` class in `Generic.dll`

```
namespace Custom
{
    public class Document : Generic.Document
    {
        public override string ObjectName()
        {
            return "Custom";
        }
    }
}
```

In my application I'm creating a `Document` object.

```
Document document = new Document();
Console.WriteLine(document.ObjectName());
Console.ReadLine();
```

When my application running if there is any way to tell the runtime if `Custom.dll` is available make `Document` object from `Custom.dll` or use `Generic.dll`?

NOTE: `Custom.dll` is not referenced to the application

EDIT:

I used the following method to create the object based on the `Custom.dll` availability. This will return `Generic.Document` object if either `Custom.dll` is not found nor couldn't load or will return `Custom.Document` if `Custom.dll` available.

```
public static T CreateObject<T>()
        {
            string zTypeName = typeof(T).Name;

            try
            {
                Assembly zLibrary = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Somewhere\Custom.dll");
                Type zType = zLibrary.GetType(string.Format("Custom.{0}", zTypeName), false, true);
                object zInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(zType);

                return (T)zInstance;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
            }
        }
```

I used the above method to like this;

```
//Custom class
           Document custDocument = Utility.CreateObject<Document>();
           Console.WriteLine(custDocument.ObjectName());
           Console.ReadLine();
```

this will return the desired `Document` object. But can't we instruct the Runtime to get assembly when creating object uisng `new` keyword?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This is where a IoC toolset like `Unity` would come in normally. You tell it `_container.Resolve<Generic.Document>()` but in your configuration somewhere you have `_container.RegisterType<Generic.Document, Custom.Document>()` so it would return the custom version when you tried to resolve the generic version.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain can you explain it with an example?

Comment: I just did in my previous comment. Go to [their web page](https://unity.codeplex.com/) and read a tutorial on it. (btw, if you did not know "IoC" stands for "Inversion of Control", this sometimes is interchangeable with "DI" or "Dependency Injection"). EDIT: Here is a direct link to the [DI tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx)

Comment: Could you use MEF instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MarcGravell found a solution to this problem.
Refer these links to the original post.

> [Link 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037732/decide-class-of-object-to-be-created-from-another-assembly?rq=1)
>
> [Link 02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-sharp-or-net?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

The code as below;

```
    public class GenericProxyAttribute : ProxyAttribute
    {
        public override MarshalByRefObject CreateInstance(Type serverType)
        {
            string zTypeName = serverType.Name;

            try
            {
                Assembly zLibrary = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Assemblies\Custom.dll");
                Type zType = zLibrary.GetType(string.Format("Custom.{0}", zTypeName), false, true);
                return base.CreateInstance(zType);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return base.CreateInstance(serverType);
            }
        }
    }

    [GenericProxy]
    public class Document : ContextBoundObject
    {
        public virtual string GetObjectName() 
        {
            return "Generic Document"; 
        }
    }
```

Now when I initialize `Document` object;

```
Document document = new Document();
```

This actually calls the `CreateInstance` method of the `GenericProxyAttribute` class. There I load the `Custom.dll` and initiate a `Document` object. Then return the `Custom.Document` object. When the `Custom.dll` is not available returns the `Generic.Document`.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common to be able to select a custom implementation for an interface. As others have mentioned, there are Dependency Injection frameworks and there is lots of information about this subject.

This does require though that the application is *configured* to select one implementation or the other - you want your application to act differently if a custom implementation is available.

Instead of having to know the *filename* of the library, you could choose to provide the `AssemblyQualifiedName` of the type:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Namespace.Type, AssemblyName", false);
if (type == null)
{
    type = typeof(T);
}

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

(Note that you can be more specific by supplying `Version=` and `Culture=`, and signed assemblies must include the `PublicKeyToken=` to be specified)

There is no built-in way to find all implementations of an interface - besides having to load and inspect all eligible assemblies and the security threat, it is generally not desired to have an application that behave differently based on the presence of a file.

Comment: I happen to have written a DI config serializer and editor, which does inspect the directory for cancidates in order to create the config file - hoping to have the best of both worlds. If you're bored, you could check it out: http://blueprints.codeplex.com