# Will an object live while there is reference to interface which It implements?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, garbage-collection

I have a class implementing an interface. I don't need a reference to objects of that class - only reference to their interfaces. It looks like:

```
interface A {}

class B : A {}

//in code:
A a = (A) new B();
```

My question is: Will instance of B to live (not collecting by GC) while I have a reference to A of that B?

Comment: You can't have a reference to an interface. You can have a reference to an object implementing an interface.

Comment: @Ace - I don't think the question ever suggested creating such; but actually, in *interop* code you *can* `new()` an interface (there's a hack in the compiler for this): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-or-net/1281522#1281522

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because you still have a reference to that `new B()` although you can see only the part that implements that interface `A`.

Answer (score 1):

The reference is the same actual value no matter whether your variable is typed as the class or the interface. So yes: it will stay alive.

Answer (score 1):

yes the instance of the object is the same, you can cast the object to any of its implemented interface, but the instance is one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because a reference to an object through an interface is still a reference to that object.

Casting an object to an interface does not create a new object, it just alters the "portal" you use to talk to the object through.

You can easily test this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
void Main()
{
    A a = (A)new B();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.KeepAlive(a);
    Debug.WriteLine("Got here");
}

public interface A
{
}

public class B : A
{
    ~B()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("B was finalized");
    }
}
```

When executed, you'll get:

> Got here

And then, optionally:

> B was finalized

But notice that B survived the full GC cycle, even though you had a reference to it through A.

Comment: Casting a class-type object to an interface does not create a new object; as you note, the compiler knows to regard the thing in question as an interface, but it's still the same thing.  Casting a structure to an interface does, however, create a new object disjoint from the original.  For this reason, structures should seldom implement interfaces except when generics can allow the interface to be used without a typecast (as with IComparable<T>).

Comment: Which is why I said 'object', but yes, structures are different.