# Object reference error when I am instantiating the object

Tags: c#, object

```
private void PerformWork(object state)
    {
        try
            {
                MMS.MMSService.Console.Program _program = new MMS.MMSService.Console.Program();
                _program.OUIProcess();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

I am getting an object reference error for _program, which I am not able to figure out. May please help me?

Here is the code:

```
public class Program
{
    // The type of connection to use, this can be:-
    // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS for a server connection.
    // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT for a non-XA client connection
    // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT for an XA client connection
    // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED for a managed client connection
    const String connectionType = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;

    // Define the name of the queue manager to use (applies to all connections)
    static String qManager = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["qManager"].ToString();

    // Define the name of your host connection (applies to client connections only)
    static String hostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostName"].ToString();

    // Define the name of the channel to use (applies to client connections only)
    static String channel = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["channel"].ToString();

    public Program()
    {

        // The type of connection to use, this can be:-
        // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_BINDINGS for a server connection.
        // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT for a non-XA client connection
        // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_XACLIENT for an XA client connection
        // MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED for a managed client connection
        const String connectionType = MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT;

        // Define the name of the queue manager to use (applies to all connections)
        String qManager = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["qManager"].ToString();

        // Define the name of your host connection (applies to client connections only)
        String hostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostName"].ToString();

        // Define the name of the channel to use (applies to client connections only)
        String channel = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["channel"].ToString();

    }
    static Hashtable init()
    {
        Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, connectionType);
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
        connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
        return connectionProperties;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>

    public void OUIProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            NRTManager ouiManager = new NRTManager();

            Hashtable connectionProperties = init();

            // Create a connection to the queue manager using the connection
            // properties just defined
            MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, connectionProperties);

            // Set up the options on the queue we want to open
            int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED  | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST;

            // Now specify the queue that we want to open,and the open options
            MQQueue system_default_local_queue =
            qMgr.AccessQueue(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queue"].ToString(), openOptions);

            // First define a WebSphere MQ message buffer to receive the message
            MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
            retrievedMessage.MessageId = MQC.MQMI_NONE;

            // Set the get message options
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions(); //accept the defaults

            // Get the message off the queue
            system_default_local_queue.Get(retrievedMessage, gmo);

            // Prove we have the message by displaying the UTF message text
            string msgText = retrievedMessage.ReadString(retrievedMessage.DataLength);

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(msgText);

            ouiManager.WriteToOUIdb(0, "Message Pulled", doc, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OUI"].ConnectionString, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MMS"].ConnectionString);

            //Close the queue
            system_default_local_queue.Close();

            // Disconnect from the queue manager
            qMgr.Disconnect();
        }

        //If an error has occurred in the above,try to identify what went wrong.

        //Was it a WebSphere MQ error?
        catch (MQException ex)
        {
            Logging logger = new Logging();
            logger.WriteToLog(1, ex.ToString(), null, null, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MMS"].ConnectionString);
        }

        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Logging logger = new Logging();
            logger.WriteToLog(1, ex.ToString(), null, null, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MMS"].ConnectionString);
        }

    }//end of start

    public static void ValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        //WriteToLog(1, e.ToString(), null, null);
        //Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code for the constructor of the Program type?

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message and the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @devdigital - a constructor cannot return null.

Comment: @Henk actually, it can (even for a class), but only if you are being deliberately malevolvent

Comment: Either the `Program` constructor or the `OUIProcess` method is probably throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I am not defining a constructor. So it is the default one.

Comment: Henk, the constructor is most likely throwing the exception, that's why i asked for the code

Comment: Constructor is throwing the error.

Comment: "Constructor is throwing the error" - but there is no constructor (defined).

Comment: @OBL do you have any field initializers? a static constructor? anything like that? is `Program` interesting *in any way*? is it a remoting proxy? a proxy of any kind, etc?

Comment: @Marc Can you show us how to be deliberately malevolent? I want to introduce the team to the `Null Constructor` pattern.

Comment: @Chris see the **second** part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194484/whats-the-strangest-corner-case-youve-seen-in-c-sharp-or-net/194671#194671) - ignore the `Nullable<T>`, which is a cheat. It works for regular `new`, `Activator.CreateInstance`, and the `T : new()` constraint

Comment: It's likely those configuration manager calls, invoking ToString on items that may not exist. Check your config files, pay attention to casing.

Comment: You said you didn't have a custom constructor, but `Program` **clearly does** (it is in the code...)

Comment: Here is the error:
InnerException = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: I added it a couple of minutes back for a hit and try run

Comment: I still couldn't figure it out. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect one of your configuration settings is missing. Check that they are all present and correct. Note that the call to `ToString` on a null value would cause the exception you are seeing.

Comment: We should expect that to raise a type-initialization exception, though, since there are also static field initializers to the same effect

Comment: Yes, he hasn't been particuarly clear on the exact error message.

Comment: In fact, looking at the code again, there seems to be some redundancy there.

Comment: In fact, looking at the code again, there seems to be some redundancy there.

Comment: Here is the error:
InnerException = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: I still couldn't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: Check your configuration settings - i.e. that your qManager, hostName, and channel application settings exist in your app.config file.

Comment: Are you able to debug and step through both the Program constructor and OUIProcess method code?

Comment: Does your queue application setting exist?

Comment: Which line is it throwing the exception on??

Comment: MMS.MMSService.Console.Program _program = new MMS.MMSService.Console.Program();

Comment: Then it's going to be your configuration settings. Try removing the static fields, then you should be able to step into your constructor, and see the line failing, and find out why. Maybe your configuration file isn't being outputted to your bin folder?

Comment: I already tried that. It demands those settings to be static.

Comment: You're removing them (commenting them out) temporarily whilst you debug the problem. Try and break the problem down.

Comment: Alternatively, change the values of those static fields to hard coded string literals, and see if the problem goes away.