# Constructor returns null for Avatar Class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono

I think class constructors in C# are not supposed to return null. But constructor of the Avatar class in Unity3D returns null. 
You don't have to be using Unity3D to have an idea. I ask how it is possible when it is not in the definition of language. Even if it has a probability of being a bug in Unity engine, is a bug like this possible?

If you use Unity, you can test with this code:

```
 [ExecuteInEditMode]
 public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
     void Update(){
         Avatar avatar = new Avatar();
         if(avatar == null) Debug.Log("Constructor really returns null.");
     }
 }
```

Few things to note:
- Avatar class inherits from UnityEngine.Object
- Other classes inheriting from UnityEngine.Object don't have this problem
- Unity uses custom version of Mono framework.

Comment: Constructor can certainly return null. [But not usually](http://stackoverflow.com/a/194671/2530848).

Comment: post the constructor of Avatar. Note that Unity objects are not supposed to be initialized with new, instead use Instantiate for game objects or don't inherit from UnityEngine.Object if you want a "regular" class (ie don't use a base class unless you have to use a specific base class).

Comment: Avatar is internal Unity Engine class.
Many other "Object"s can be initialized with new. It is only natural since C# works like this and internally, the Unity engine also calls these constructors. If Unity developers didn't want us to initialize the object this way, they would make constructors private.

Comment: I found this a few minutes ago.  I threw an unnecessary "if (this.myobj == null) return;" check in a function, and I don't know why I did that. Anyway, it lead to me falling on my face, and finding this post. I'll simply not check for null, despite the object it references being properly existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the `==` operator is overloaded and maybe checks for something different than the actual object. For any class that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object` you should not instantiate the class via `new`. You have to do use `UnityEngine.Object.CreateInstance`.

Comment: Actually, I noticed the problem by getting a NullReferenceException. It is still possible, the exception is thrown after checking equality against null internally. I will check if the reference is actually null.

Comment: In "normal" code no constructor can return null. It's simply not possible

Comment: You were probably right. Reference is not null. Probably == operator is overloaded.