# NullReference Exception in multithread program for reading data

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my C# win form project, I read some data by web service. It takes a few time, so I have a thread for reading like this:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
{
    SMSCenter_RecievedMessages = (new SMSCenterGetMessages()).getMessages());

    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        if (SMSCenter_RecievedMessages != null && SMSCenter_RecievedMessages.Length != 0)
        {
            // some code
        }
    }));
});
```

after 2 days running, some time I get this exception:

```
Null Reference Exception was unhandled : Object Reference Not set to an instance of an object.
```

Is it possible that before creating a new of object, `getMessage()` function is accured? Because I did it by thread. what is the wrong by this code?

Thanks for any helping?

Comment: At which line you are getting the exception ? coz I don't find Nullreference possibility in your current code. . .

Comment: @RohitPrakash I got it in SMSCenter_RecievedMessages = (new SMSCenterGetMessages()).getMessages()); that will accure few times

Comment: In that case, off course, SMSCenterGetMessages object is not being created at the time. Try using Parallel stacks to figure out the exact case.

Comment: @RohitPrakash how is it possible that `new` does not instantiate a new object and results to a `null` instead?

Comment: @zerkms, Douglous has explained it all.

Comment: @RohitPrakash no they have not. Douglas explained possible race condition in next lines (which does not actually play well with what OP stated few comments above). So my question is still open - how do you think it's possible that `new` does not initialize an object?

Comment: There are only rare cases where a class constructor can return `null` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/194671/1149773). It's unlikely that the OP is actually getting the `NullReferenceException` on that line (unless it's thrown from *within* the constructor).

Answer (score 2):

One possible cause of your error is that `SMSCenter_RecievedMessages` is presumably declared as a class field. If your code snippet can be executed multiple times in succession (e.g. from a click event handler), then this could lead to race conditions.

Suppose that an event handler causes your code snippet to start getting executed. The background thread populates `SMSCenter_RecievedMessages` with a non-null value, and dispatches control to the UI thread. The UI thread evaluates `SMSCenter_RecievedMessages != null` to `true`.

In the meantime, another event handler had caused your code snippet to start getting executed again (concurrently). This time, `getMessages()` returns `null`; this is assigned to the same `SMSCenter_RecievedMessages` field and overrides the previous value.

In the meantime, the UI thread has continued execution, and attempts to evaluate `SMSCenter_RecievedMessages.Length != 0`. Since the field has now been set to `null`, a `NullReferenceException` ensues.

Comment: OP stated that `SMSCenter_RecievedMessages = (new SMSCenterGetMessages()).getMessages());` is the line that causes a null reference exception.

Comment: @zerkms: The clarification was stated in a comment after the original question had been posted. In the absence of further information, the race condition on the `SMSCenter_RecievedMessages` field is still the likeliest explanation.

Comment: I agree that for the original question it would be the most possible explanation (if only we ignore the last lines, where OP also refers to `getMessages()` explicitly), but OP stated it's the `(new SMSCenterGetMessages()).getMessages())` expression that fails. Which I personally don't believe, but we have what we have :-)

Comment: Thanks for your good idea, but I used Lock() for whole this code, that I think it solves this race condition. but the unhandled exception is accure yet.

Comment: @Elahe: I would suggest making `SMSCenter_RecievedMessages` a local variable instead, so that different executions of your code would not conflict with each other. If you don't use the field elsewhere, then this should be sufficient. If you do use the field elsewhere, then the lock needs to be applied for all uses, which might lead to UI freezes or deadlocks.