# Do you use the "this" operator in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages

#### Duplicate post, see: [When do you use the "this" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

---

On almost every project I worked the "This" operator is used, when i start developing i was told that it is a good practice. is this really necessary does it gives you more readability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools like Resharper have a built in hint saying "redundant qualifier," but I disagree with it and quickly disable the rule.

I always use the this qualifier because it lets me know at a glance whether or not the reference is a property/field, or a static class ref for example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}

public MyClass MyRef { get; }
```

or

```
public static class MyRef {
   public static int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

so:

```
void method() {
   MyRef.Foo = 4; // might be either
}

void method() {
   this.MyRef.Foo = 4; // definitely property/field
}
```

Just my 2c.

-Oisin

Comment: what a contrived example. why do you optimize for the infrequent case?