# In C#, is "this" keyword required?

Tags: c#

In the following constructor, is the 'this' keyword required? I know I can remove it, it complies and everything is okay. If I omit 'this' will that cause problems for me down the road? Is ommission of 'this' considered bad practice?

```
    // Constructor:
    public Employee(string name, string alias)
    {
        // Use this to qualify the fields, name and alias:
        this.name = name;
        this.alias = alias;
    }
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, `this` is purely optional in almost all cases.  The only reason it is required in your example is to disambiguate between local variables and parameters and member variables that happened to have the same identifier name.

You could avoid the use of `this` by renaming either the parameter or the field to something unique.

Comment: So it IS NEEDED. if he doesn't use this, then the code won't work correctly.  Will it even compile without "this"?

Comment: It will compile but with warnings.

Comment: The reason it is required is that the compiler would assume that `name` meant the parameter, not the field in all cases where `this` was omitted.  Obviously it would compile but there would be logical errors in the program.

Comment: "this" can also differentiate with member methods if the class implements a base class (base vs. this).

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you need it in your code example. C# will always assume you mean local variable, so if a member variable and a local variable exist with the same name, you *must* use `this`, otherwise it will be assumed that you are referring to the local variable.

In your code example, if you neglect the `this`, you are effectively assigning `name` (or `alias`)'s value to itself (thus accomplishing nothing).

Answer (score 5):

in the case below `this` is absolutely required.  But you can get around it by choosing variable names carefully.  In my humble opinion, there is nothing wrong with the example below and I do not mind having to use `this`.  In fact, I often use `this` even when it is not required just to prompt intellisense and auto-complete in my IDE.

```
internal class Something
{
    private string name;
    public Something(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's optional, *unless* you have a member variable named 'name', in that case, your line there will be assigning to itself.

I always like to access all member variables with "this", just to be explicit. Some people like to use "_" as a prefix, or even "m".

Comment: I've been using the "_" but lately I'm finding a fair amount of sample code, like that shown above, that uses the 'this' keyword, hence the question.

Comment: I prefer the 'this' since it can't be a mistake; someone may accidentally name a local variable "_", but with `this`, it's always obvious.

Comment: @sikly: proper tools can prevent accidental local variables with leading "`_`". So can human eyes.

Comment: I prefer to use the most basic of all tools (the compiler) to find my errors.

Comment: @Scott -- that is likely to be a result of people starting to use the StyleCop tool on default settings to automate coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

In C# it is most common to either name the private variable _Name or m_Name.  This also makes it easy to visually match up Properties because if you have a property Name, which uses a local private variable _Name, it is easy to see quickly what it is for.

Without the this keyword in your example, all you are doing is assigning the local variable to the local variable (and not to the private variable).  Which is why it compiles, but won't do what you think it is doing.

Comment: Actually, the use of sigils like _ or m_ is against the MSFT coding guidelines as embedded in the FxCop and StyleCop tools; the MSFT coding standard is to require the "this." prefix, even if not actually necessary to distingish a field from a local vaRIABLE.

Comment: @SteveGilham is right, don't use m_ prefixes in your C# code

Answer (score 0):

in your example, if you don't use "this" something worse will happen: "Variable Hiding"