# C# optional parameter besides null for class parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the best solution to this problem?  I'm trying to create a function that has several optional parameters of class types for which null is a meaningful value and cannot be used as a default.  As in,

```
public void DoSomething(Class1 optional1, Class2 optional2, Class3 optional3)
    {
        if (! WasSpecified(optional1)) { optional1 = defaultForOptional1; }
        if (! WasSpecified(optional2)) { optional2 = defaultForOptional2; }
        if (! WasSpecified(optional3)) { optional3 = defaultForOptional3; }

        // ... do the actual work ...
    }
```

I can't use `Class1 optional1 = null` because null is meaningful.  I can't use some placeholder class instance `Class1 optional1 = defaultForOptional1` because of the compile-time constant requirement for these optional parameters I've come up with the following options:

1. Provide overloads with every possible combination, which means 8 overloads for this method.
2. Include a Boolean parameter for each optional parameter indicating whether or not to use the default, which I clutters up the signature.

Has anyone out there come up with some clever solution for this?

Thanks!

**edit:** I ended up writing a wrapper class for so I didn't have to keep repeating `Boolean HasFoo`.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A wrapper for variables indicating whether or not the variable has
    /// been set.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    public struct Setable<T>
    {
        // According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208%28v=vs.71%29.aspx,
        // "[s]tructs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors" and "[s]truct
        // members are automatically initialized to their default values."  That's fine,
        // since Boolean defaults to false and usually T will be nullable.

        /// <summary>
        /// Whether or not the variable was set.
        /// </summary>
        public Boolean IsSet { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The variable value.
        /// </summary>
        public T Value { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts from Setable to T.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p_setable"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static implicit operator T(Setable<T> p_setable)
        {
            return p_setable.Value;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts from T to Setable.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="p_tee"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static implicit operator Setable<T>(T p_tee)
        {
            return new Setable<T>
            {
                IsSet = true
              , Value = p_tee
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Overloads won't let you pass the literal null constant. (Just a style issue.)

Comment: What exactly are you attempting to accomplish here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would at least *consider* creating a new type for the parameter:

```
public void DoSomething(DoSomethingOptions options)
```

... where DoSomethingOptions could look like this:

```
public class DoSomethingOptions
{
    private Class1 class1;
    public bool HasClass1 { get; private set; }

    public Class1 Class1 
    {
        get { return class1; }
        set
        {
            class1 = value;
            HasClass1 = true;
        }
    }

    ... for other properties ...
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
DoSomething(new DoSomethingOptions { Class1 = null, Class2 = new Class2() });
```

You don't end up with an exponential set of overloads, and you can still call it reasonably compactly.

This is similar to the approach that `Process` takes with `ProcessStartInfo`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, Jon.  I'll go with this unless I hear about some way to get around that compile-time constant issue.

Answer (score 6):

> Provide overloads with every possible combination, which means 8 overloads for this method.

This is my preference.  It makes the situation very clear and maintainable.  Internally, you can map to a single initialization routine to reduce duplicated code.

Comment: In this scenario (8 overloads) it can be considered somewhat maintainable. But, this clearly would **not** be maintainable as more parameters are required. Just imagine if he had 5 parameters... that's 32 variations! yes, it is more clear in its own way, but maintainability takes a huge hit. Then again, CA1026 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182135.aspx does state to not use optional parameters for public access... it's just a lot of craziness.

Comment: @m-y Realistically, it's rare that EVERY parameter is or should be optional, though - so it's only the meaningful ones.  If every parameter is optional, I'd refactor into a more meaningful data structure.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, that's consistent with Jon Skeet's answer below.  I will mostly likely use a transfer object as you and Jon suggest, since I might have more than three optional parameters.  m-y is right that the variations will get excessive.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Your second comment, that is, is consistent with Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 6):

I'd prefer making `null` mean "nothing," and have a `static readonly` member of type `Class1`, `Class2`, etc. on `Class1`, `Class2` etc. named `None`. Then instead of making `null` meaningful you can use null as "nothing" as it was originally intended.

In case that's confusing:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static readonly Class1 None = new Class1();
}
public static Class2
{
    public static readonly Class2 None = new Class2();
}
```

Note, that if `null` in your case means something other than "None" (like "MissingData" or something else) you should name the member thusly.  Also note: this will make a lot more sense to other people reading and using your code in the future.

Comment: Also see Null Object pattern for related info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern (and +1)

Comment: +1 - Yes, I agree whole heartily. Instead of taking away the **true** meaning of null, have a static field that represents a "Nothing" value. It's kind of like `String.Empty` vs null.

Comment: Like I said, I'm trying to _avoid_ using `null` to mean "Nothing" or "Unspecified".  In this case, `null` is meaningful.  In your example, how would I use Class1.None as a default parameter without getting "Default parameter value for 'optional1' must be a compile-time constant"?

`public void DoSomething(Class1 optional1 = Class1.None)` gets me that error.  Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: @Don, would you mind explaining *how* null is meaningful? You're fighting against C#'s semantics...Also, you *wouldn't* use Class.None as a default parameter, you'd use null, and then inside the method you'd start out by saying, `class1Parameter = class1Parameter ?? Class1.None`

Comment: @Don01001100: You'd flip the usage... `Class1.None` would represent whatever you're using **null** to represent now, and null would represent itself. So you'd default all your optional parameters to null and use `Class1.None` to replace whatever null was representing. Don't use null to give additional meaning to something other than it being null. Again, look at `String.Empty`. It literally is a string that represents "Nothing" instead of using null to represent "Nothing".

Comment: thanks @m-y lost my ability to express what I was trying to explain

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  That makes sense now.  Basically, what I'm going for is providing any instance of the class, null, or "unspecified" as a parameter to this method.  If you don't specify, the method will make something up for you.  This code is for creating objects for testing, so, e.g., you a test that sets `Person` object's `Car` property to null to test a `Person` with no car, a test that sets it to a specific `Car` instance to see how that `Person` interacts with that `Car`, a test where you don't care, so you'd leave the parameter out and let the function assign a default.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Flags` enumeration that you can pass along to mark which classes to use.

```
[Flags]
public enum DoSomethingOptions
{
    None = 0,
    UseClass1 = 1,
    UseClass2 = 2,
    UseClass3 = 4,
    etc..
}

DoSomething(Class1 class1, ..., DoSomethingOptions options = DoSomethingOptions.None) { ... }
```

Then simply pass that enumeration in to mark which classes to use. I do wonder why you used `null` to mean something other than **null**? Although this might be a solution, I'd really like to say "rethink your design".

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, try using an object. Define a class which encapsulates the possible choices. When a choice is set in the object you can store in that same object if it was set through the use of the setter of the original property.

An example:

```
internal class SettingsHolder
{
    public SettingsHolder()
    {
        IsOriginalPropADefault = true;
    }

    private Class1 originalProp;
    public Class1 OriginalProp
    {
        get
        {
            return originalProp;
        }
        set
        {
            originalProp = value;
            IsOriginalPropADefault = false;
        }
    }

    public bool IsOriginalPropADefault { get; private set; }

}
```