# C# Create default value for class, e.g. through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, default-value, default-constructor

Let's say I have a class `A`:

```
public class A 
{
    private int value;
    public A() => value = 0;
    public A(int value) => this.value = value;
}
```

And I have some method, with a parameter list where some are defaulted:

```
public void SomeMethod(int i, float f, string s = "", A a = null)
```

Now is there some way, e.g. through reflection, to be more smart about this parameter list? I would like to be able to do something like the following, so I don't need to check for null everywhere:

```
public void SomeMethod(int i, float f, string s = "", A a = Default) // should use the empty constructor!
```

Is this possible with C#?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727395/c-sharp-optional-parameter-besides-null-for-class-parameter

Comment: The closest thing to a default in c# is the `default operator` which would still be `null` in case of a reference type. Why can't you allow for a null and do the check once in the method's implementation?

Comment: Is that Method "Client-Facing"? If so, you need to validate parameters anyway. If it is actually OK to _pass_ `null` , then you could use overloading as in Innat3's answer or use the Null-Object Pattern or just do `var localA = a ?? new A();`

Comment: @LennartStoop Because I have a similar pattern many places in the code base, and having 0 as default int parameter is way better than having null for a class reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could use method overloading

```
public void SomeMethod(A a, int i, float f, string s = "") { }

public void SomeMethod(int i, float f, string s = "")
{
    SomeMethod(new A(), i, f, s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[CONCLUSION]**

It is not possible in C#. The `default` operator returns null for all reference types, and for value types it initializes all data fields using `default` operator. So in my case, I can actually omit this problem using a struct instead of a class:

```
public struct A 
{
    private int value;
    public A(int value) => this.value = value;
}

public void SomeMethod(int i, float f, string s = "", A a = default)
```

And then the input value will be `a : A{value = 0}`.

A general solution for using a class does not exist in C#, since default values are required to be determinable by compile time and must thus be constant expressions. Only valid constant expressions in C# are primitives, value types, and strings.