# How do I make the C# constructor syntax more pythonic?

Tags: c#, python, constructor, default-constructor, object-initialization

I have some background in the python initializer (essentially Python object constructor syntax), and the syntax to instantiate an object in Python is as follows:

```
class Account:
     def __init__(self,name=None,address="Not Supplied",balance=0.0):
         this.name = name
         this.address=address
         this.balance=balance
```

Why is it, in C#, I have to provide defaults in the body of the constructor method, when in python I can declare them as optional, and default values are passed in (see the `__init__`'s signature):

```
public class Account
{
    private string name; 
    private string address;
    private decimal balance;

    public Account (string inName, string inAddress, decimal inBalance)
    { 
        name = inName; 
        address = inAddress; 
        balance = inBalance; 
    }

    public Account (string inName, string inAddress) 
    {
        name = inName; 
        address = inAddress;
        balance = 0;
    } 

    public Account (string inName) 
    { 
        name = inName;
        address = "Not Supplied";
        balance = 0;
    }
}
```

Why can't I do the following in C#?

```
public class Account
{
    private string name; 
    private string address;
    private decimal balance;

    public Account (string inName, string inAddress="not supplied", decimal inBalance=0;)
    { 
        name = inName; 
        address = inAddress; 
        balance = inBalance; 
    }
```

Is it possible to have constructor syntax in C# that is similar (if not an exact duplicate) to Python's initializer syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.. the second C# snippet should match your python snippet (ignoring the semicolon).

Comment: I don't understand... is the last snippet how you would like it to work? Because it actually does work that way.

Comment: @default.kramer: Last snippet was how I was expecting it to work. Does it work that way?

Comment: Yes, starting from C# 4.0

Comment: Did you try it? (The answer is yes)

Comment: Oh my!! I was reading C# yellow book and never saw a word suggesting the last one might work. I made a fool of myself then if the last snippet works.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Press the blessed "play" button.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades If that is the biggest fool you've made of yourself while programming, you still have a long way to go. :p

Comment: @Bart: Is that a word of solace or sarcasm?

Comment: I'm probably merely reflecting my stupid mistakes onto you, hoping I'm not alone. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been done using [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

> Visual C# 2010 introduces named and optional arguments. Named
>   arguments enable you to specify an argument for a particular parameter
>   by associating the argument with the parameter's name rather than with
>   the parameter's position in the parameter list. **Optional arguments
>   enable you to omit arguments for some parameters.** Both techniques
>   can be used with methods, indexers, constructors, and delegates.
>
> The definition of a method, constructor, indexer, or delegate can
>   specify that its parameters are required or that they are optional.
>   Any call must provide arguments for all required parameters, but can
>   omit arguments for optional parameters.
>
> Each optional parameter has a default value as part of its definition.
>   If no argument is sent for that parameter, the default value is used.

Answer (score 5):

You should look into [Constructor Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814953/c-sharp-constructor-chaining-how-to-do-it).  Basically boils down to constructors calling other constructors to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: This would be the best option pre-C# 4.0

Comment: @crashmstr Ah, didn't know about the named and optional arguments in C#.  I don't typically use C# but constructor chaining is language agnostic and reading OP's code duplication hurt my insides.  Optional arguments are definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I program in C# and Python, so here's a view from someone who recently went from C# to Python:

C# provides a default constructor if you do not create one.

So, by default (if you didn't have a constructor already), you could instantiate the object with its defaults like follows:

```
var Account = new Account();
```

This would instantiate those properties with their respective default values.

If you provide a constructor, you must then provide the default constructor as well (if you intend on constructing an object just by: `var account = new Account();`:

```
public Account() {} //default constructor

public Account(string name)
{
    Name = name;
}
```

The other primitive types in your class are initialized according to their default values.

If you'd like something Pythonic, you need to be sure you're using C# 4.0; [we call them Optional Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).  Their usage (in your case) would be exactly as you wrote it:

```
public string Name { get; set;} 
public string Address {get; set;}
public decimal Balance {get; set;}

public Account (string name, string address="not supplied", decimal balance=0;)
{ 
    Name = name; 
    Address = address; 
    Balance = balance; 
}
```

A few style comments:

- In C#, we use properties.  They aren't used quite the same way in Python, and in Python you'd be more likely to use fields.  Our properties are PascalCased.
- We don't use 'in' and 'out' parameters as part of the parameter name (there's no need to, we have `ref` and `out` for when we need to pass references -- sadly something that is missing from Python (although not really sad because it makes code more complex)).
- In C#, fields are Camel cased -- or `camelCased`, as it were.  In Python, they'd follow Unix conventions: `first_name` as opposed to firstName.
- In C#, your properties are `public` by default, and they should be.  In Python, everyone assumes `public`, `private` is only assumed if an underscore precedes the variable -- not so in C#.

Comment: @crashmstr If you intend to use the default constructor's offerings,  you must provide a default constructor if you have multiple constructors. If you have no constructors, the default is provided for you, and can be safely removed from your code with no issue.

Comment: I could be wrong -- I'm not saying I'm not -- I'm just going off of memory.  I moved from programming in C# full time to Python full time about 8 months ago, so it's entirely possible that I've forgotten something. I do know that NHibernate will require a default constructor if you've provided another constructor.  If I had my .NET Dev platform up right now I'd test my theory.

Comment: I'm looking at a class that has two constructors, both with arguments, and no constructor with no parameters defined. So how is that "must"? Of course, this might prevent code from working that requires a default constructor in a class.

Comment: Perhaps not so much a "must" as a "won't generate one for you".

Comment: @crashmstr What happens when you instantiate an object of that class without any parameters?

Comment: Can't. There is no default constructor like @Bart says. Sometimes, that is the whole point. You need to build the object with the required parameters, or not at all.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think the distinction he's getting at is that the compiler won't complain if you never use it without any parameters. If it would, then it would be a "must".

Comment: @Bart That makes sense. I've updated my comment to reflect a more accurate state of affairs: If you intend on using the default constructor to instantiate an object of a class, you have to provide it if you have multiple constructors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more short hand approach you can use the object initializer.

```
public class Account
{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public string Address { get; set; } 
   public decimal Balance { get; set; } 
}

var account = new Account { Name = "Dave" };
```

Answer (score 0):

As of VS2010 (I believe C# 4.0) C# does allow [named and optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) similar to how you use them in Python.

Unfortunately, older versions of C# don't have this (I think somewhat due to C#'s Java legacy, but this is just speculation on my part).

Answer (score 0):

C# allows you also to utilize object initializers:

```
public class Account
{
    public string name { get; set;} 
    public string address { get; set;} 
    public decimal balance { get; set;} 
}

Account acc = new Account () { name="Some Name", address="Some Address", balance=10.0 }
```

You can that way specify dynamically which fields you want to initialize.