# C# how to inherit from default constructor

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, default-constructor

I have a simple class with 2 constructors.

The first (default) constructor that takes no parameters constructs all the properties so they are not null once this object is instantiated.

the second constructor that takes an int parameter does a lot more logic, but it also need to do exactly what the default constructor does with regards to setting up the properties.

Is there away I can inherit from this default constructor so im not duplicating code?

code below...

```
public class AuctionVehicle
{
    public tbl_Auction DB_Auction { get; set; }
    public tbl_Vehicle DB_Vehicle { get; set; }
    public List<String> ImageURLs { get; set; }
    public List<tbl_Bid> Bids { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPrice { get; set; }

    #region Constructors

    public AuctionVehicle()
    {
        DB_Auction = new tbl_Auction();
        DB_Vehicle = new tbl_Vehicle();
        ImageURLs = new List<string>();
        ImageURLs = new List<string>();
    }

    public AuctionVehicle(int AuctionID)
    {
        // call the first constructors logic without duplication...

        // more logic below...
    }
}
```

Comment: move the code to another function say init and call it from both the constructors. but hey, inheriting is not the correct word here.

Comment: This isn't inheritance, it's called constructor chaining or constructor telescoping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# constructor chaining? (How to do it?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814953/c-sharp-constructor-chaining-how-to-do-it)

Comment: @Jack that works unless you are setting fields that are `readonly`, then they cannot be set from the `Init()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public AuctionVehicle(int AuctionID) : this() 
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public AuctionVehicle(int AuctionID) : this()
    {
        // call the first constructors logic without duplication...
        // more logic below...
    }
```

Or factor it out to a private method which contains the common logic.

Answer (score 2):

```
public AuctionVehicle(int AuctionID)
    : this()// call the first constructors logic without duplication...
{
    // more logic below...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

inheritance from constructor is not allowed in c#

Reason :-

If constructor inheritance were allowed, then necessary initialization in a base class constructor might easily be omitted. This could cause serious problems which would be difficult to track down. For example, if a new version of a base class appears with a new constructor, your class would get a new constructor automatically. This could be catastrophic.

Comment: 1) This isn't inheritance really, OP only has one class. They just used wrong term. 2) You can call base constructors of your choice e.g. `MyConstructor : base() {}`. Though you are right that these are not automatically inherited. Base constructors are ineffect the same as `protected` methods but only available to direct descendants.