# The use of inherited GUID

Tags: c#, guid

Can anyone please explain the purpose of using the syntax like this :

```
public ClassConstructor() : 
    this(Guid.NewGuid(), 0, new List<Transaction>(), "")
{
}
```

The code looks like this :

```
public BankAccount()
    : this(Guid.NewGuid(), 0, new List<Transaction>(), "")
{
    _transactions.Add(new Transaction(0m, 0m, "account created", DateTime.Now));
}

public BankAccount(Guid Id, decimal balance, IList<Transaction> transactions, string customerRef)
{
    AccountNo = Id;
    _balance = balance;
    _transactions = transactions;
    _customerRef = customerRef;
}
```

Comment: [Constructor chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1814953/2065121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the line below known as `constructor initializer`

```
public ClassConstructor(): this(Guid.NewGuid(), 0, new List(), "")
```

With the above line whenever call to parameter less constructor `ClassConstructor()` happens it first calls the parameterized constructor `this(Guid.NewGuid(), 0, new List(), "")` of the same class `ClassConstructor` and then code/body of the `ClassConstructor()` get processed

Comment: What is the advantage of this.. and in what scenerios we shud use like this?

Comment: @user3615920 You use this to avoid duplicating initialization logic. One constructor (generally the one with the most parameters) contains the logic common to all/most constructors. Other constructors delegate initialization to this common constructor.

Answer (score 1):

@JasonEvans answer is actually a little bit wrong. He mixes up `base` with `this`.

You can use `this` to delegate a constructor call to another constructor within the scope of the class:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    // 1st constructor
    public BankAccount()
        : this(Guid.NewGuid(), 0, new List<Transaction>(), "")
    {
        _transactions.Add(new Transaction(0m, 0m, "account created", DateTime.Now));
    }

    // 2nd constructor
    public BankAccount(Guid Id, decimal balance, IList<Transaction> transactions, string customerRef)
    {
        AccountNo = Id;
        _balance = balance;
        _transactions = transactions;
        _customerRef = customerRef;
    }
}
```

In your example the first constructor delegates it's call to the second constructor, before it executes itself. So in your example the `BankAccount` get's initialized with an empty list of `Transactions`, when the default constructor is called. After this, the first `Transaction` ("account created") get's added.

Answer (score -1):

It's the same as to write:

```
public BankAccount()
{
    AccountNo = Guid.NewGuid();
    _balance = 0;
    _transactions = new List<Transaction>();
    _customerRef = "";
    _transactions.Add(new Transaction(0m, 0m, "account created", DateTime.Now));
}

public BankAccount(Guid Id, decimal balance, IList<Transaction> transactions, 
                   string customerRef)
{
    AccountNo = Id;
    _balance = balance;
    _transactions = transactions;
    _customerRef = customerRef;
}
```