# C# object initializer

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, object-initializers

I am trying to understand some code for my programming exam and I've stumbled upon this notation that I can't seem to find the explanation for. **I've searched stackoverflow, msdn and several online tutorials, but no luck.**

The code is something like this:

```
class A
{
    public A(): this("b")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("c"); 
    }

    public A(string i)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(i); 
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public B()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("a"); 
    }
    ---------------
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        A b = new A(); 
    }
}
```

This, supposedly, prints out "bc", but I can't even understand the inheritance and all.  I can't find out what is this notation here does:

```
public A(): this("b")
{
     Console.WriteLine("c"); 
}
```

The only thing I found that looked remotely similar are object initializers, but only in one online tutorial. Checked MSDN for them - no similar code. Anyone able to help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the specification section on constructor syntax?

Comment: [It's called `"Constructor Chaining"`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814953/c-sharp-constructor-chaining-how-to-do-it)

Comment: What 'notation' in particularly is confusing to you?
`:this("b")` will call the class A parameterized constructor and simply prints "b" and then the A parameterless constructor is called - printing "c".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with object-initializers. Its about [constructor-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1814953/2528063). When any method (including constructors as well) has such a `this(...)` what you say is as very first call that overload with the similar signatur, so in your case `this("b")` will first call this ctor:  `public A(string i)`. After this call has been done the actual work within that particular constructor is done, in your excample `Console.WriteLine("c");`.

Comment: If I've understood this correctly, the order of calling would be: superclass constructor, chained supercass constructor, subclass constructor. But what if I had a matching constructor in a subclass, but none in the superclass? In the given example, if I had public B("M") {} and called it in Main()?

Comment: You have to provide any sort of construrtor-chaining, be it implicitly or explicitely. In your case as you already have a base-class-constructor with matching signature (`public A(string)`) that one would be called before your ctor for class `B`. If class `A` hadn´t such a ctor a compiler-error would be generated. This chaining ensures that every derived object is fully initialized including all of its base-members.