# Generics params Richter code

Tags: c#, generics

I learn generics. Richter LinkedList. I have questions about class initialization.
Added: There is 2 constructor. First with null. **How we can do it with 1 one constructor?**

```
internal sealed class Node<T> 
{
    public T m_data;
    public Node<T> m_next;

    public Node(T data) : this(data, null) 
    {
    }

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) 
    {
        m_data = data; m_next = next;
    }

    public override String ToString() 
    {
        return m_data.ToString() + ((m_next != null) ? m_next.ToString() : String.Empty);
    }
}
```

What is?

```
public Node(T data) : this(data, null) 
{
}
```

especially `(T data)`

Why I can do?

```
 public Node(T data, Node<T> next)
        {
            m_data = data; m_next = null;
        }
```

But I can not do

```
 public Node(T data, Node<T> next)
        {
            m_data = null; m_next = next;
        }
```

Comment: The constructor takes an instance of the generic constraint `T`. Quick example, type Node<string> would take `string` in the constructor.

Comment: Your Node class's constructor takes a parameter which named `data` type of T

Comment: There is 2 constructor. First with null. How we can do it with 1 one constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How we can do it with 1 one constructor?

You can use optional parameters in the constructor

```
internal sealed class Node<T> {
    public T m_data;
    public Node<T> m_next;

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next = null) {
        m_data = data;
        m_next = next;
    }

    public override String ToString() {
        return m_data.ToString() + ((m_next != null) ? m_next.ToString() : String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Which would allow for usage like

```
var node1 = new Node<string>("hello world"); //the same as (data, null)
var node2 = new Node<string>("how are you", node1);
```

> What is `public Node(T data) : this(data, null)` ?

Its called constructor chaining/overloading.

Take a look at [C# constructor chaining? (How to do it?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814965/5233410)

Answer (score 1):

That's a example snipped from a LinkedList.

`T` is a placeholder for your type. So if you  use `Node<int>` you set the type to be an integer - which is generic. `data` is the variable name within the constructor.

The usage of `Node<int> foo = new Node<int>(1);` 
is the same as `List<int> foo = new List<int>();` which might be familiar to you

> There is 2 constructor. First with null. How we can do it with 1 one
>   constructor?

You can remove one if it isn't needet or set a default value like this to replace both:

```
public Node(T data, Node<T> next = null)
{
    m_data = data; m_next = next;
}
```

Comment: There is 2 constructor. First with null. How we can do it with 1 one constructor?

Comment: @ifooi updated my answer. If you're interested in LinkedList, i've implemented one recently http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138142/linked-list-in-c