# Chaining constructors not updating variables as expected

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a class that looks similar to the one below. As you can see I created a few constructors that I am trying to chain using `: this()`

```
class RTTutils
{
    #region Variables

    private bool verbose = false;
    private bool canWrite = false;

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public RTTutils()
    {
        x = 5;

        y = 5;

        RTTCalc();
    }

    public RTTutils(int samples, bool verbose) : this()
    {
        this.verbose = verbose;
        this.samples = samples;
    }

    public RTTutils(int samples, bool verbose, bool canWrite) : this()
    {
        this.verbose = verbose;
        this.samples = samples;
        this.canWrite = canWrite;
    }

    public RTTutils(int samples) : this(samples, false, false)
    {
    }

    public RTTutils(bool verbose) : this()
    {
        this.verbose = verbose;
    }

    private void RTTCalc()
    {
        if (this.verbose)
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
```

I am trying to initialize it using

```
RTTutils rttcalculator = new RTTutils(true);
```

or any other combination for `verbose` and `canWrite`, they still remain `false` though. As an example in this case we will see nothing printed in the console, even though I indicated `true` when initializing the class.

What am I doing wrong in this case?

Comment: You need to provide an example that can actually reproduce your problem.  As it is it is not complete enough to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: "they still remain `false` though", when, where, and how are you obtaining this information?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1814953/215552

Comment: You expect (wrongly) boolean class fields used in method `RTTCalc` to have values you set in constructors with parameters. However, the parameterless constructor executes before these assignments.

Comment: @Igor shouldn't the constructor `public RTTutils(bool verbose) : this()` be executed first, since that's what Im calling.

Comment: In `public RTTutils(bool verbose) : this()` the parameterless constructor is run before the one with the `verbose` parameter. That means `RTTCalc` is run before the `verbose` field is set to `true` in the chaining constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect (wrongly) boolean class fields used in method `RTTCalc` to have values you set in constructors with parameters. However, the parameterless constructor executes before these assignments.

Do not call `RTTCalc` in parameterless constructor. Provide static factory methods instead:

```
class RTTutils
{
    private bool verbose = false;
    private bool canWrite = false;

    private RTTutils()
    {
        sampleList.Add(100);    // First sample should be 100
        optionChosen.Add("E");

        x = 5;
        y = 5;

        System.IO.File.Delete(this.path);
    }

    private RTTutils(bool verbose) : this()
    {
        this.verbose = verbose;
    }

    private void RTTCalc()
    {
        if (this.verbose)
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }    

    public static RTTutils Create(bool verbose)
    {
      RTTutils result = new RTTutils(verbose);
      result.RTTCalc();
      return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your code above, I rewrote it and it initializes verbose and canWrite as expected.

class Foo
    {

```
    private bool _verbose = false;
    private bool _canWrite = false;
    private int _samples;
    private int x;
    private int y;


    public Foo(int samples, bool verbose, bool canWrite)
    {
        _verbose = verbose;
        _canWrite = canWrite;
        _samples = samples;
        x = 5;
        y = 5;

        RTTCalc();
    }
    public Foo() : this(0, false, false) { }

    public Foo(int samples) : this(samples, false, false) { }

    public Foo(int samples, bool verbose) : this(samples, verbose, false) { }


    private void RTTCalc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"V={_verbose}, S={_canWrite}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo test1 = new Foo(1, true, false);
        Foo test2 = new Foo(1, true);
        Foo test3 = new Foo();

    }
}
```

Does this work for you?  If not then you are doing something else that is not shown in your code that is affecting verbose and canWrite.