# c# - Object Oriented Programming Factory Method Contructor

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

In C# and constructor dependency injection what is the difference between the first two constructors. Specifically what does the `:this` in the first constructor signify. Is it just shorthand for the second constructor or something else?

```
    private readonly IRepositoryOne _repositoryOne;
    private readonly IRepositoryTwo _repositoryTwo;
    private readonly IService _service;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MyContructor()
        : this(new RepositoryOne(new ApplicationDbContext()), 
               new RepositoryTwo(new ApplicationDbContext())
               new Service())
    {

    }

    public MyContructor()
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _repositoryOne = new RepositoryOne(_context);
        _repositoryTwo = new RepositoryTwo(_context);
        _service = new Service();
    }


    public MyContructor(IRepositoryOne repositoryOne,
                        IRepositoryTwo repositoryTwo,
                        IService service)
    {
        _repositoryOne = repositoryOne;
        _repositoryTwo = repositoryTwo;
        _service = service;
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814953/c-sharp-constructor-chaining-how-to-do-it

Comment: @L.Guthardt the first one calls the 3rd one.

Comment: @Nkosi so inorder to use my dependency injection constructor should i be using constructor number two and get rid of constructor number one so that I'm using the same context?

Comment: @adam78 This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve? 'Cause I would remove first two constructor and let the DI container inject the explicit dependencies into constructor 3

Comment: @Nkosi I want to use dependency injection using constructor but I need to use the same application db context for the repositories. Note I dont have a DI container.

Comment: @adam78 Then create the instances externally and Pure DI them into the dependent class.

Comment: @Nkosi I'm trying to ask how I can do it with the above example and no DI container. Which constructor should I be using the first or second?

Comment: @adam78 use second constructor based on the desired functionality

Comment: @Nkosi. Thankyou.

Comment: Having multiple constructors is [an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: @Steven my programming is not up to your high standard but thanks for the tip. However in all honesty in my many years of programming no one ever bothers to look under the hood regardless of whatever pattern you use as long as the applications chugs along.

Answer (score 1):

You should not create the first 2 constructors because the dependency injection container will handle how to create the repository and the service.

The `this` keyword is used in scenarios like

```
Public Person(string name){}

public Person(string name, string lastname) :this(name)
{ 
    // calls first constructor and then..
    // do something with lastname
}
```