# Calling a Constructor within Super Class

Tags: inheritance, super

I am learning how to make a superclass. I have been successful setting it all up I just need help learning how to call a default constructor.

Here is what I have Superclass file:

```
public class Date {

private int month;
private int day;
private int year;

Date() {

}

Date(int passedMonth, int passedDay, int passedYear){
   month = passedMonth;
   day = passedDay;
   year = passedYear;
}
```

SubClass:

```
public class GregorianDate extends Date {
//*************** Constructors ***********************
GregorianDate() {
    long numToAdd = System.currentTimeMillis();
    numToAdd += java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
    numToAdd /= 86400000;
    super.addDays(numToAdd);
}
//Parameterized constructor
GregorianDate(int passedYear, int passedMonth, int passedDay){
    super(passedMonth, passedDay, passedYear);
}
```

What I need to do is call the default constructor in the sub class to update the correct default constructor to today's date. somehow in the superclass to assign the month, day, and year values.

Comment: Update to understand what is your question?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Comment: Thats the page I was looking at and it still didn't quite make sense. Also update the question a little to make a little more sense.

Comment: Go through the link it might help you "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814953/c-sharp-constructor-chaining-how-to-do-it"

Answer (score 0):

The super class should have its own initialisers in the constructors that you can selectively override in the sub class constructors.

Which is not possible unless you have the super class in code.

Hope this addresses your doubt.

Comment: So, am I even close with the attempt I have going right now?

Comment: Change the default constructor in the super class and assign the month, day and year.

Comment: so do like month = what tho? How can I can I call the subclass constructor since that does all the math?

Comment: I dont expect anyone to do it for me but lead in in the right direction/hint would be awesome.