# Dotnet Core Default Constructor Call parameterized With IOption<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a class with a parameterized constructor with an `IOptions<TOptions>` parameter to access the connection string. Now I need to create a default constructor for my project purpose. Now I want to trigger the parameterized constructor from the default constructor. How can I do that?

Comment: For example: `public MyClass() : this(parameter to be passed to the ctor with parameter) { // implementation }`

Comment: Thanks Dimitar. But now i want to pass IOption with settings like this public ValuesController():this(IOptions<Config> configSettings) { }. I am getting  following error Using the generic type 'IOptions<TOptions>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: You cannot do this. You must provide an actual object instance like (new DefaultOption) where the Default option is implementing the IOption interface.

Comment: @SATHEESHP `default constructor` means `no parameters` by definition. Why do you want to use the *default* constructor at all, when you need parameters? Register your class as a service and the DI/Configuration middleware will inject the values you want. During testing just pass an Option class with the hard-coded values

Comment: @SATHEESHP what is the *actual* problem you want to solve? If you want a fallback value you can set it during configuration. If you want to target different databases, configure your DbContexts or any other class you want to target the correct database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# constructor chaining? (How to do it?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814953/c-sharp-constructor-chaining-how-to-do-it)

Comment: **You need to use a factory pattern.**  The factory class gets the `IOptions<settings>` from in its constructor, and it also has a method called `Create()` that creates a new instance of your class by calling the other constructor that you want to call (with the required parameters).

Answer (score 2):

From the default constructor, you can invoke the parameterized constructor (by using the `this` keyword) with an instance of the [OptionsWrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.Options.optionswrapper-1) class, which implements the [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1) interface:

```cs
public class ValuesController
{
    public ValuesController()
        : this(new OptionsWrapper<Config>(new Config() { ConnectionString = "default ConnectionString" }))
    {
    }

    public ValuesController(IOptions<Config> configSettings)
    {
    }
}

public class Config
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you may use [Options.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.options.create), which actually does the same: [Options](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Options/Options/src/Options.cs)

```cs
Options.Create(new Config() { ConnectionString = "default ConnectionString" });
```

However, either of these solutions - especially if used in the context of [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) - entirely defeat the purpose of [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/) and [Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

Comment: That's a bad idea. It hard-codes the settings and *duplicates* the configuration already stored in the configuration subsystem. The config middleware can read data from dictionaries, environment variables, multiple setting files that allow specifying a fallback connection quite easily and safely

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree this should be done before the constructor as you mentioned in the comments above; but the question, regardless of configuration logic, was answered.  Possibly just answer it with showing how to call one constructor from another; passing default values would be more ideal. That is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814953/c-sharp-constructor-chaining-how-to-do-it