# How to create instance of class that have parameterized constructor

Tags: c#

One of interviewer asked me this question: How to create instance of class that have parameterized constructor, but i will not send the parameter information. Example:

```
public class abc{
     public abc(string str)
     {
     }
}
```

Now if we create instance of it then i have to do it in this way:

```
abc abcInstance = new abc("xyz");
```

But he wants  that he will not pass parameter eg.:

```
abc abcInstance = new abc();
```

Please help me out. Some one suggested Dependency Injection Please share an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like you are looking for [Constructor chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1814965/2417602)....?

Comment: declare another constructor: `public abs(): this(null) {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

string is nullable, but you can do this:

```
public class abc{
     public abc(anyType str = defaultvalue)
     {
     }
}
```

If anytype is int, use defaultvalue as 0 for example and etc...

Comment: thanks for your response, but if you can give an example of Dependency Example it will help me.