# Failed to desirialize the SecurityIdentifier class

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have to deserialize a json string that contains the AD users:

```
[
  {
    "DistinguishedName": "CN=Guest,CN=Users,...",
    "DisplayName": null,
    "FirstName": null,
    "LastName": null,
    "SamAccountName": "Guest",
    "ObjectGuid": "some guild...",
    "Mail": null,
    "IsEnabled": false,
    "SecurityIdentifier": {
      "BinaryLength": 28,
      "AccountDomainSid": {
        "BinaryLength": 24,
        "Value": "some value"
      },
      "Value": "some value"
    },
    ...
    }
  },
  ...
  ]
```

And my class looks like:

```
  public class MyClass
    {
        public string DistinguishedName { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public SecurityIdentifier SecurityIdentifier { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

The deserializing with

```
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<MyClass>>(json);
```

works fine until I try to deserialize the SecurityIdentifier field.

> Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor
>   is not supported. Type 'System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier'

Any idea to handle this? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the problem is in the SecurityIdentifier class that has no parameterless constructor and deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be. But the SecurityIdentifier class is sealed and I can't inherit from it to create my own class with a default constructor.

Comment: You could try creating a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=netcore-3.1) for the `SecurityIdentifier`

Answer (score 0):

As adviced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61124257/9868549), you can try switching to NewtonSoft to deserialize you json.