# Should I use «this.» keyword in OOP programing where it's possible to skip it? Any benifits of using it?

Tags: performance, oop, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When do you use the “this” keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

In OOP sometimes we can write `this.PropertyName = VALUE` and sometimes we can skip `this`. and just write `PropertyName = VALUE`.

My questions:

1. Should we try always to use `this.`?
2. Does using / writing `this` have any effect on application performance or does it just make the code a little bit clearer?

Comment: Try writing a benchmark for it. I'd guess that they are identical in compiled languages.

Comment: If they aren't, you have a bad compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference in performance. Its purely a style decision.