# To Use or Not To Use the 'this' qualifier in C#

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use the “this” keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

I have just started using Resharper to analyze my code and there are many things it has suggested that I do and I am really pleased with its output as it is also teaching me a few better methods for doing things.

Obviously its suggestions can be ignored and one of these I would just like to get some feedback from the community on!

I have always preferred to use the 'this' qualifier for properties that belong to the current class (i.e this.Name). No real reason - I just seemed to adopt this many moons ago.

Resharper suggests that this is redundant and maybe I should remove it.

What do you think?

Comment: There are definitely some duplicates of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/725770/should-the-java-this-keyword-be-used-when-it-is-optional and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920279/should-i-use-this-keyword-in-oop-programing-where-its-possible-to-skip-it-an

Comment: You know those dreams where you're in class or at work and you're not wearing any clothes? That's how member property or method references without `this.` make me feel.

Comment: Considering the analogy, wearing clothes in this case would be a unnecessary, borderline neurotic behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the important things to remember is that `this` is removed by the compiler and so it is purely a matter of 'what looks good to you and those with whom you share code?'. It will affect performance not a whit.

Comment: Thanks - that's my main concern - whether my preference for doing something is less optimized for performance.

Answer (score 18):

Preferably, i use `this` only to prevent ambiguity between (possibly) a property and a function parameter

```
public class thing
{

   private string name;

   public thing(string name)
   {
       this.name = name; // will set private string name to param string name
   }

}
```

If you are already working in the context of a certain class, it's not so hard to keep this in mind, and i do not need to be reminded of the fact that I am addressing a local variable every time i address one.

So I think ReSharper's right on this one.

Answer (score 12):

I find it redundant particularly with a well defined coding standard:

```
Name // Property
_name // Member field
name // local variable
```

Using `this.<whatever>` just seems to be more work.

Comment: This still does not solve the base. qualifier functionality.

Answer (score 9):

I personally think that it's a good practice to use `this` keyword because it's clearly marks does prorerty/method/etc belongs to object instance or not. This is especially useful then private members are named so that local variables are indistinguishable from private members:

```
/// some pretty long method
/// ...
frameCount += 1; // is it private memeber or some local defined above?
```

Needless to say it's probably better not to use it at all than use inconsistenly.

However I find that constant usage of `this` makes code look "noisy" with `this` being unuseful distractor. IMO it's better to use special `_` prefix naming for private members:

```
/// some pretty long method
/// ...
_frameCount += 1; // it's clearly private memeber!
```

it's also much faster to type.

Comment: I agree with `_fieldName` as private. This is a known convention in other languages like python.

Answer (score 8):

One advantage of using this. is intellisense. It narrows the list of things you could pick faster.

Comment: you can use Intellisens by pressing CTRL + SPACE without this

Comment: @oleksii: I didn't know that - learn something new every day!

Comment: anytime, there is also CTRL + SHIFT + SPACE, I can't remember what is difference

Comment: If  that's your reason for using "this", I'd say your type might have too much responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

It is technically redundant, but StyleCop (if you're being picky and using the full set of Microsoft coding standards) says you should use it.

I do, lots of people don't, so I guess it's down to personal preference or the coding standard at your employer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case its a preference - so you prefer to use it, tell resharper that and it will stop complaining.