# When to use this keyword style guidelines?

Tags: asp.net, coding-style

I wanted to know what various guidelines state about the usage of this. Sometimes I use "this." to get the auto popup help versus to make any distinction of the code. I feel this is sorta bad style but can't say for certain.

What do various C# and .NET style guidelines state about trivial this usage?

(Editors please don't remove this post. This is a legitimate question because I am phrasing it as what style guidelines state about this and not opinion where style guidelines are formal guidelines, i.e that one can find on the net and are published.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use the "this" keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use control space in the editor to pull up the intellisense box. You should reserve using this explicitly to situations where not using it would cause confusion.

Comment: And what style guide did you pull this out of?

Answer (score 0):

It makes more sense to use 'this' than to resort to a naming or prefix scheme in order to be less ambiguous.  Since the point is usually to make code more readable using 'this' allows for clearer interpretation and less chance of bugs.