# The this reference?

Tags: c#, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use the “this” keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

Can anyone explain me the "this" reference? when we use this ? with a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `this` inside a class, you're refering to the current instance: to the instance of that class.

```
public class Person {

    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName) {

        //How could you set the first name passed in the constructor to the local variable if both have the same?
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    //...
}
```

In the above example, `this.firstName` is refering to the field `firstName` of the current instance of the class `Person`, and `firstName` (the right part of the assignment) refers to the variable defined in the scope of the constructor.

So when you do:

```
Person me = new Person("Oscar", "Mederos")
```

`this` refers to the instance `Person` instance `me`.

**Edit:**
As `this` refers to the class instance, cannot be used inside static classes.

`this` is used (too) to define *indexers* in your classes, like in arrays: `a[0]`, `a["John"]`,...

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a scope identifier. It is used within an object's instance methods to identify behaviors and states that belong to an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays-fashionable [Fluent APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.23) use `this` extensively. Basically it's used to get hold of a reference to the *current* instance.

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple example

```
public class AnObject
{
  public Guid Id { get; private set;}
  public DateTime Created {get; private set; }

  public AnObject()
  {
    Created = DateTime.Now;
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
  }

  public void PrintToConsole()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("I am an object with id {0} and I was created at {1}", this.Id, this.Created); //note that the the 'this' keyword is redundant
  }
}

public Main(string[] args) 
{
  var obj = new AnObject();
  obj.PrintToConsole();
}
```