# Clarification on `this` keyword

Tags: c++, pointers, this

Sorry if it a trivial question:

Implementation 1:

```
class Foo
{
    protected: int bar;

    public: Foo(int bar)
      {
        this->bar =bar;
      }
};
```

Implementation 2:

```
class Foo
{
    protected: int bar;

    public: Foo(int bar)
      {
        this.bar =bar;
      }
};
```

Output from implementation 2:

`request for member ‘x’ in ‘this’, which is of pointer type ‘Foo* const’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)`

so `this` is a pointer, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword) question has syntax error in code

Comment: This is something fundamental - (raw) pointers can be used only with `->`, and not with `.`.

Comment: FYI - `C++` & `C#` are 2 different languages.

Comment: I come from Java. Somethings are lost in translation
@user93353 the code is tagged C++ && C#. My bad though

Comment: @aiao: I have removed the C++ tag from the linked question, as the code was clearly not C++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you are referring to contains code samples written in C#, not C++. Yes, in C++, `this` is a pointer and must be dereferenced to access any members of the object it points to.

Comment: sorry about that it was tagged with c++, so assumed they wold be the same. Thanx

Comment: Actually this is a pointer in C# too, but C# has got a sort of automatic dereference :)

Comment: @BlackBear Thanks, I don't know any C#. I think my edit doesn't suggest anything about C# now.

Comment: @BlackBear: no, it's not "a sort of automatic dereference". The `.` operator in Java and C# is simply how you write the C++ `->` operator in those languages. Different languages write their operators differently.

Comment: @newacct in C# you use the dot operator both for structs (which value types) and classes (reference types). If the dot is applied to a struct it is equivalent to the C++'s dot while if it's applied to a class it actually operates as the C++'s arrow.