# Class constructor for List<string>

Tags: c#, class, constructor, initialization

I've the following class

```
MyClass
{

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<string> FriendNames {get;set;} 

    public MyClass()
    {
       FriendNames = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Is it correct to initialise the List like I've done or should it be

```
this.FriendNames = new List<string>;
```

Is there any difference ?

Then in my code I can create a instance like

```
MyClass oMyClass = new MyClass();
oMyClass.Id = 1;
oMyClass.Name = "Bob Smith";
oMyClass.FriendNames.Add("Joe King");
```

Comment: Usually when you have a collection in a class you will mark it `{get; private set;}` so external users can not replace the underlying collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When do you use the "this" keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `this.FriendNames = new List<string>;` is exactly the same as `FriendNames = new List<string>;` `this` will count only when you will have variable with name same as your property.

like here:

```
public MyClass(List<string> FriendNames)
{
    this.FriendNames = FriendNames; // here we have to specify which FriendNames is from this class
}
```

Constructor is for initializing some resources, so initializing your list there is a good idea.

You can create constructor with name and id (if you are always assigning them)

```
public MyClass(string name, int id)
{
   FriendNames = new List<string>();
   Name = name;
   Id = id;
}
```

and change your code to:

```
MyClass oMyClass = new MyClass("Bob Smith", 1);
oMyClass.FriendNames.Add("Joe King");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference. So it boils down to preference.

Some people like to because it is very explicit and self commenting. Others feel that it clutters the code.

The important thing is that you are instantiating the `List` in the constructor. Something that too many people forget to do.

The accepted answer in this SO question has a nice list of when to use the `this` keyword

[When do you use the “this” keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
FriendNames = new List<string>();
```

Or

```
FriendNames = new List<string>(123456);
```

if you know the capacity before upon initialization.

Comment: both are not compiling, also this does not provide answer to the question

Comment: I've edited to fix compile time error. And what do you meant by "123456"? You mean what you're doing? You're pre-setting list's capacity to 123456

Comment: Thank you @Sriram, and yes just any number supposing it's need capacity is known.

Comment: @Recursor And how this can help OP?

Comment: @wudzik Prior to an edit, there were no parens after list so it would not compile. Also 'this.' before is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
    private List<string> list = new List<string>();

    public List<string> List
    {
        get { return list; }
        set { list = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating a list should be something like

```
FriendNames = new List<string>();
```

If you're asking whether the `this` is required, if your constructor took a list of `FriendNames` such that there is ambiguity in what you mean, then you'd have to use `this` to indicate that you want to assign it to the object's instance.

```
public MyClass(List<String> FriendNames)
{
   this.FriendNames = FriendNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `this.FriendNames = new List<string>;` you see that this is a class-variable with the first glance.

Especially in large classes with many variables this can be an advantage as you can easier/faster distinguish class-variables from local variables.

But as many other here stated this is up to your preference.

Where this is getting important is if you have a class and a local variable with the same name like this:

```
MyClass
{
    public List<string> FriendNames {get;set;} 

    public SetMyList(List<string> FriendNames)
    {
       this.FriendNames = FriendNames;
    }
}
```

In this case you have to use the `this-keyword`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to initialise an instance of your class

```
var x = new MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "Steve", 
            FriendNames = { "John", "Paul", "Ringo", "George" } };
```

And generally don't use "this." references, I rarely see it used in this way (often I use the only remnants of any kind of Hungarian notation left in my code by prefixing private fields with "_" so at least

```
public void DoSomething();
{
   _myInt = 123;
}
private int _myInt;
public int MyInt { get { return _myInt; } }
```

Means I know whats going on, but I'm sure people out there won't like the "_".

Comment: using `new MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "Steve", ` should be replaced with constructor

Comment: You're offering an alternative - explicity writing a constructor to take a set of parameters.  But this is not "the right way" to  do it.  When microsoft introduced this style of initialiser list it meant I didn't have to write multiple overloaded constructors anymore.   Most of the time you want to be able to flexibly create and initialise an object, constructors don't let you do this.