# How does the value assignment operator work in this case?

Tags: c#, oop

It helps to note I'm very new to c#.

But consider the following class:

```
class AllItems
{
    private readonly Database database;

    public AllItems(Database database)
    {
        this.database = database;
    }
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. In the above example we are assigning `private readonly Database database`the value which gets passed into `AllItems` class, is that correct?
2. Would it matter if I swapped `this.database = database` around, so it looked like `database = this.database` instead?
3. Where we are saying `this.database`, does `this` refer to the database in `AllItems(Database database)` or does it refer to `private readonly Database database` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In the above example we are assigning private read-only Database database the value which gets passed into the AllItems class, is that correct?

Yes

> Would it matter if I swapped `this.database = database` around, so it looked like `database = this.database` instead?

Yes, it would. What you would end up doing there is assigning the database *parameter* being passed in to be the value of the database *field* (which would be `null` by default).

> Where we are saying `this.database`, does this refer to the database in AllItems(Database database) or does it refer to private read-only Database database?

[`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is shorthand for the current class instance, therefore it refers to the private read-only member of database.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes
2. Yes it would matter, then you would assigning the value of `this.database` (in this case `null`) into `database`.
3. `this.database` in this case refers to `private readonly Database database;` field. I suggest you read more about the `this` keyword [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dk1507sz.aspx).

Comment: yes, I mean that it refers to that field as opposed to the argument being passed in the constructor. I have corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it's correct, you can set a readonly field in the class constructor, that's the only place we can initialize readonly fields/properties.
2. It matters the fact that the swapping does a meaningless thing. When you do this `database = this.database`, the `database` is assigned to the value of `this.database` which is null in this case, but that local variable is not used and will become unavailable outside the constructor.
3. `this.database` of course references the private field of your class. In this case the private field and the argument have the same name so we have to use the `this` to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) In the above example we are assigning private readonly Database database the value which gets passed into AllItems class, is that correct?

Yes, `this` is used to refer to objects that are declared in the class.

> 2) Would it matter if I swapped this.database = database around, so it looked like database = this.database instead?

Yes it would, if you swap it then instead of assigning the value in database declared as parameter in the constructor to the `private readonly Database database`, it would assign the value in `private readonly Database database to the database declared as a parameter in the constructor.

> 3) Where we are saying this.database, does this refer to the the the database in AllItems(Database database) or does it refer to private readonly Database database ?

`this` is a keyword used to refer to variables declared in the class also know as global variables therefore it refers to `private readonly Database database`.

Also take a look at [When do you use the "this" keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)