# What is the use of the "this" keyword after a constructor?

Tags: c#, avalonedit

The following code is from the AvalonEdit project:

```
// Creates a new TextEditor instance.

public TextEditor() : this(new TextArea())
{
}
```

I have no idea what the `: this(new ...` part does. Could you please help explain the C# syntax?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - the dupe question wasn't a dupe and the answer only usable with the instructions from your comment here.

Comment: Considering that the marked duplicate question doesn't actually list constructor chaining as an option, I would have to say that it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I thought "To pass parameters between constructors" link in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword is reasonable explanation...

Comment: OK, doh, read the list 3 times, still didn't spot that entry. Perhaps too late on a friday evening for me. I agree, the duplicate lists it. (and no, I did not vote to reopen). In my defense, "pass parameters between constructors" is not a very good description of the operation being performed. But oh well. Too late on a friday :)

Comment: So, it's equivalent to the following (albeit illegal) syntax: `public TextEditor() : TextEditor(new TextArea())` - now I understand it.

Comment: @Sabuncu please edit your question so it looks reasonable "please explain code" is awful title. Maybe something along line "what 'this` after constructor means"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what would you suggest? Is "What is the following use of the "this" keyword?" acceptable?

Comment: @Sabuncu - definitely better than current. Maybe mention constructor too.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your contributions - 20 mins ago, I was completely lost.  Now it's all clear, thanks to SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that this constructor calls another constructor which accepts argument of type `TextArea`. It is called *constructor chaining*.

See the link provided by @Lasse:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645603(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks! I hope you do not mind that I inserted your link into the answer. It is more canonical than the one I used before.

Comment: Not at all. It did not warrant an answer that would be better than yours anyway.