# Column provided does not belong to this DataGridView control

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to sort a datagridview column on radiobutton checkchanged? When i try the below code an Exception is raised

```
private void rdoBookedOn_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn bkon = grdBookingView.Columns[3];

        grdBookingView.Columns[3].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
        this.grdBookingView.Sort(this.bkon, ListSortDirection.Descending);

    }
```

ArgumentException is raised on this line

```
this.grdBookingView.Sort(this.bkon, ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

I've tried this in designer

```
this.grdBooking.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

The screenshot of the gridview

[image]

Comment: `this.bkon` ? Shouldn't it be local `bkon` (**without this**)?

Comment: @Sinatr I had just copied the sort code from net. What's the difference between this.bkon and local bkon?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23250/1997232). If it was *compiler error*, then you have to read about `this`. If it was *runtime exception*, then you have somewhere field/property in form class with name `bkon` (same as your local variable).