# this.variable inside the class etc

Tags: constructor

I'm reading an [android app](https://github.com/trinhcongvuong-uet/application_cnpm/tree/master/TestToeic/app/src/main/java/com/uet/cnpm/testtoeic/items) and do not understand why the constructor in the `ListeningQuestion.java` uses `this.variable = variable` in its own constructor, but only `variable = variable` (no this) in the `ListeningQuestionItem.java`. They both have `variable` declared as `private` in the respective class. Why the differences? Any help?

Comment: `ListeningQutionItem` is actually using bad naming conventions. Variables should start lower-case (No hard reason, it's just convention). In that case, they would use `this.` to differentiate between the class variable and the parameter.

Comment: java variables names are case senstive. In case of Local variables with same name as of instance variable name `this` is used to identify the instance variables. refer my answer below for more , hopefully it will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/42358555/504133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO

> > Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called.

An object has state, and in case there are same local variables of same name as of the instance fields then fields can be accessed using `this` keyword.

`this.listeningFileID = listeningFileID;`

In this case there is one instance variable named as `listeningFileID` which is accessed using `this` and other is the local variable which is passed as a parameter to the constructor.

Java variable names are case senstive.  In the second case

`ListeningQuestionContent = listeningQuestionContent;`

Observe the first character , the field name is **L**isteningQuestionContent and the local variable passed as parameter is named as **l**isteningQuestionContent. Here we do not have same names so `this` js not used (although this is same as `this.ListeningQuestionContent = listeningQuestionContent;`)

Comment: so in the second case, listeningQuestionContent = listeningQuestionContent will not work unless it differs by the case?

Comment: It will not be a compile error. It will be simply assignment of local variable (method parameter) to itself.

Comment: local variable will shadow the instance variable. to acess the instance variable in such a case when you have same named local variable then you need to use `this.`

Comment: @g_studio if you found my answer helpful then you have option of accepting it

Answer (score 1):

The constructor as declared in [ListeningQuestion.java](https://github.com/trinhcongvuong-uet/application_cnpm/blob/master/TestToeic/app/src/main/java/com/uet/cnpm/testtoeic/items/ListeningQuestion.java) you are looking -

```
public ListeningQuestion(String listeningFileID, String listeningSoundAddress, String listeningImageAddress,
                         ArrayList<ListeningQuestionItem> listeningQuestionItems) {
    this.listeningFileID = listeningFileID;
    this.listeningSoundAddress = listeningSoundAddress;
    this.listeningImageAddress = listeningImageAddress;
    this.listeningQuestionItems = listeningQuestionItems;

}
```

If we see the constructor, the name of the `parameter` is same as the name of `private variable`.

By specifying, `this`, I am explicitly asking to assign the value of parameter to the local variable. `This` signifies the instance to current class.

In case I do not use `this` keyword, the value will not be assigned to local private variable, but re assigned to the parameter value itself, because it has narrower scope.

It is a common convention to assign the parameter values to local variable this way.

Some stuff [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword) about using `this` keyword

Now if you see the constructor of [ListeningQuestionItem.java](https://github.com/trinhcongvuong-uet/application_cnpm/blob/master/TestToeic/app/src/main/java/com/uet/cnpm/testtoeic/items/ListeningQuestionItem.java),
The names of parameters and local variable, differs by case. And because there is no ambiguity, you can assign the value to private variable, without using `this`, as -

```
ListeningQuestionID = listeningQuestionID
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll take a look at the links provided.