# What is the difference between those 2 methods?

Tags: java, methods, this, setter

Method number 1:

```
public void setAge(int newAge){
    age = newAge;
}
```

Method number 2

```
public void setAge (int age){
    this.age = age;
}
```

Comment: One uses an argument with the same name as a class field, the other doesn't.

Comment: Functionally they are exact equivalents.

Comment: This may be of use to you why `this` is important:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502/1792481

Answer (score 5):

In both, it must be assumed that the object has a field called `age`.

### Second Version

In the second one, there is also a parameter called `age`. Since the parameter `age` has the same name as the field `age`, it "**hides**" the field. So, within the second version, anywhere you see `age` will be referring to the parameter, not the field.

Since the field is hidden, you need a way to still access it. You can still get at it by using the `this` reference. `this` refers to "this" object, and `this.age` accesses the field instead of the parameter. So field `this.age` is set to parameter `age`.

### First Version

The first version just avoids this ambiguity by using a different parameter name so that **the field is not hidden**, so it still sets field `age` to the parameter but *does not need the `this.` prefix*.

Answer (score 1):

Both are setter methods which is a common convention to assign values to private variables inside the class, both the methods have the same functionality, the first method is assigning a value to the class field called age while the second is also assigning a value to the same variable but that variable is shaded by the age parameter because their names are the same, so to change the field `age` instead of the local parameter that is only available inside the function you need to use `this.age` which means you want to change the field not the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, it is clear both variables are different, so no problem.

But in the second case which `age` you are explicitly specifying which `age` you are referring to and it is a good practice. We add `this.age` so that compiler knows you are referring to **class variable** not **local variable** in left side and right side **local variable** `age`

Comment: The question is not clarity, it's the rules of the language. The compiler knows perfectly well what the semantics of 'age = age;' is.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `setAge` function is a member function of a class that has a member variable `age`: Both codes will change the value of `age` to the argument passed to the function.

Having said that, second method is considered a good practice where you are explicitly specifying that you want to change the member variable of the current object by using `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I think that age is a member of the class you use. In this case in second method the argument got a same name as member class so you need to use `this` specifier inside a method to specify that you want to assign a new value to a class member.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are the same, will do same thing, but standard is to use

```
public void setAge (int age){
     this.age = age;
}
```

with "this.age" (this-meaning the age of your object) and with the same parameter name as the field.