# Does "this" always know the calling object?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, this

I would like to avoid writing the same line of code in all my derived classes. I have the following structure:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class BaseClass
{
    public string BaseProperty { get; set; }
    public string Serialize() { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this); }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string DerivedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

What happens when `Serialize()` is called from `DerivedClass`? Is `this` smart enough to know that the child object contains an extra property? Or, am I limited to writing this same line of code in each child of `BaseClass`?

Comment: Yes. `this` is very smart to know that.

Comment: Also check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

Comment: Thank you @CodeNotFound. I think I was misunderstanding some of the usages described here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some language features / behaviors are easy to experiment with... Considering the following code:

```
public class A
{
    public string WhoAmI => this.ToString();
}

public class B:A { }
```

Your question is equivalent to asking what `Console.WriteLine(new B().WhoAmI)` prints out?

Well, if in doubt, run it and see... it takes less than 1 minute.

`this` is a reference to an object, and behaves as any other reference, it simply has a special name.

Considere the following:

```
A a = new B();
```

Now you have a `B` instance referenced by an `A` typed reference `a`, but the instance is still a `B`. In your case `this` inside `BaseClass` is simply a `BaseClass` reference to whatever instance has been created. Do not confuse the type of a reference pointing to an object with the type of the object itself, they need not be the same.